# underscore throttle + ensure last call

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout, throttling, underscore.js

Underscore provides the method, throttle.  From their docs:

Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

Now imagine the case of an autocomplete form.  This means that if 'abc' is typed within a, say, 100ms window, then only a search for 'a' will be sent, and not 'bc'.

Is this a drastic oversight on the part of underscore.js?  What would you suggest as a clean solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this use case, you may want to use the following "buffer" function, which will apply only the last call within the wait window.

https://gist.github.com/2484196

```js
_.buffer = function(func, wait, scope) {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    var args = arguments;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      timer = null;
      func.apply(scope, args);
    }, wait);
  };
};
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1. Still, I'd not add it to the `_` object because this may confuse someone that reads your code. *"Was this method from an older version of Underscore? Is this a [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) extension?"*

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party but the accepted answer is a debounce function not a throttle + I have a more versatile throttle function which can act as a normal or a debounced version to ensure the last call gets fired after the delay is over. So essentially combining throttle and debounce into one if you wish to

```
function throttle(f, delay = 0, ensure = false) {
  let lastCall = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  let wait;
  let handle;
  return (...args) => {
    wait = lastCall + delay - Date.now();
    clearTimeout(handle);
    if (wait <= 0 || ensure) {
      handle = setTimeout(() => {
        f(...args);
        lastCall = Date.now();
      }, wait);
    }
  };
}
```

How it works:

- It is foremost a simple throttle function, where you can call it if the last call was longer ago than the `delay`
- You can set a flag `ensure` to make the throttle function ensure the last call will get called if it was called in between "frames"

  - For example if you throttle a function to 1 call per second it means it will only fire when the last call is longer than 1 second ago
- If you call the throttle function with the `ensure` flag enabled while the last call is e.g. less than 1 second away, e.g. 600ms, then the throttled function simply sets a timeout to call the function in 400ms (`wait = lastCall + delay - Date.now()` - here if `lastCall = 0` and `delay = 1000` and `Date.now() = 600` then the time out will happen in `400`)
- Otherwise if you wish to treat it as a simple throttle function just don't set the `ensure` flag and calls in between "frames" will just be ignored.

I think this is an elegant solution to add more functionality to a simple throttle function. I use it to move things around in an editor while keeping the redrawing at a certain framerate but still make sure that movements that should have happened in between frames are still ensured to be applied

Comment: This is working but somehow does not during unit tests

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I didn't read the docs right! There *is* a function for this.

```
var test = _.debounce(function() { console.log('foo'); }, 3000);
```

Then if you call `test()` a few times you'll notice that only after three seconds since the **last** call, will the function ever be called.

This is *exactly* what we both were looking for... and didn't notice was right below `throttle` on the docs.

[Underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce), [Lo-Dash docs](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) ([what is LoDash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898916/124119))

Comment: While this seems to work in this use case, debounce and throttle give a different behavior. I'm looking for a way to keep the requests going through while typing, but still ensure the last call (as in the question here).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the other answers mention using debounce instead of throttle. I found a solution that allows you to keep throttle behavior (keeping function calls going through) while still ensuring the last call.

https://gist.github.com/ayushv512/a2f963bface38f5e2f6f6bba39bba9b9#file-throttle-js

```
 const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let lastFunc;
  let lastRan;
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    if (!lastRan) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      lastRan = Date.now();
    } else {
      clearTimeout(lastFunc);
      lastFunc = setTimeout(function() {
          if ((Date.now() - lastRan) >= limit) {
            func.apply(context, args);
            lastRan = Date.now();
          }
       }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is kinda bad/wasteful. The first if condiiton should be replaced with the if condiiton in the setTimeout. ``lastRan`` is only before the first call falsy, so ``if (!lastRan)`` doesn't make sense anymore after that. Conversely the ``if ((Date.now() - lastRan) >= limit)`` in the setTimeout is out of place because you set a timeout to call the function when it is allowed to be called again and therefore doesn't need to be gated again. This if condition should hence be replaced with the ``if (!lastRan)`` so that you only set a timeout when the function was called inbetween frames

Answer (score 1):

I keep an [`idle` function](http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2012/02/idling-with-underscore-js/) around to handle this type of user interaction. The idea is to require some function to be called at a regular interval (i.e, when a key is pressed in an input); as soon as the interval passes without a call to said function, a separate callback is triggered. This might not be quite the behavior you want for your autocomplete (you might want to start searching before the user's input has paused), but it's one approach I've used in the past.

If anyone has a better solution for this, though, I'm all ears!

Comment: that's good to know (especially the _ mixin!), but not exactly the same- I definitely want results to appear while people type.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I think the tricky part is deciding where to draw the line with respect to the user's typing speed and the delay in getting a response from the AJAX request. Without some kind of googlesque pre-fetch, it seems like the request will (necessarily) lag behind user input. More pondering needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that it won't work well for an autocomplete form. I think it's meant for other types of things, though. The example given is handling scroll events.