# How do I prevent duplicate Angular keys in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having trouble with duplicate keys in NG-Grid.  Search for Tim then click on ng grid column in gridOptions1 to see duplicates in gridOptions2.  Any ideas?

Here's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NN9TIN0SEhNVqiHvhmTS?p=preview)

```
$scope.gridColumnDefs2 = [
 {displayName:'Phone', cellTemplate: 
 '<div data-ng-repeat="(key, ngClickResult) in ngClickResults track by $index">{{ngClickResult.phone}}</div>'},
```

Comment: try `(key, ngClickResult) in ngClickResults track by $index`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `track by` to solve this, unless there is some reason you should not, try `track by $index`  - that usually does the trick!

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, ngClickResult) in ngClickResults track by $index">
```

Or if you're actually trying to remove the items from the data you can filter , something like this from this answer here - [AngularJs Remove duplicate elements in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat)

Although If you use this second method, unless you are really stuck I would recommend trying to modify the data coming in before it hits the repeat - maybe on the server if you have access to that.

Comment: @Angular_Newbie You would need to use a filter like the example question in the gridOptions2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Ok.  Looking into that now.  Thanks ajmajmajma.

Comment: ajmajmajma.. That helped.  It's working now..  http://plnkr.co/edit/NN9TIN0SEhNVqiHvhmTS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Angular provide the `unique` filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result | unique:'_id'">
    //Body here
</div>
```

Comment: but this will give only the unique elements but how the user will find the duplicate elements ...