# How to make chckbox list based on checkbox check nd uncheck using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have object which contains mobile brand with models.i have included my object here

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.items= [{


    id: "986745",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 735 TS"

}, {

    id: "896785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Nokia Asha 230"
}, {

    id: "546785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 510"
},
{

    id: "144745",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Trend 840"
},

{

    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
},
{

    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos"
},
{

    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
},
{

    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note Duos"
},

{

    id: "232980",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Htc One X9"
},
{

    id: "456798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 820"
},
{

    id: "656798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 810S"
}

]
```

})

My Expectation:
here i am having 3 mobile brands with respective models.when i come to this page it should show 3 checkboxes (below i given)

1. Nokia
2. Samsung
3. Htc

if i click nokia then it should show Nokia mobile models with checkboxs
like (list with checkbox)

1. Lumia 735 TS
2. Nokia Asha 230
3. Lumia 510

if i click Samsung or Htc then it should show respective models like nokia

when i submit i should get only checked checkbox values both brandname and modelname any one help me out

Comment: pls check this https://jsfiddle.net/7pLsqhkg/3/ .if i want to add price for that particular model ?.i have added text box but when i submit it did't get value i am getting undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a filter that filter the unique value.

[AngularJs Remove duplicate elements in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat)

It will be better if you have the brandnames in a separate array. Anyway. Create checkbox with that filter. Each checkbox will have a separate `ng-change` that will fire if you check/uncheck that box. On a check you will push the brandname to an array with selected brandnames. On uncheck you will remove brandname from that array.

Okey. So now we have our selected brandnames in an array. Next you will put into your html a nested `ng-repeat`. The first `ng-repeat` will iterate the selected brandnames and the second `ng-repeat` will iterate the items array. In the second `ng-repeat` you will have `ng-if` that will filter the models by comparing the current item brandname with the current parent brandname.

Example nested `ng-repeat` html:

```
<div ng-repeat="brand in selectedBrands">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.brandname === brand">
    // checkboxes and stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

Later if I have time I might post some more code if you are still unable to code it yourself ;)

**EDIT:**

Here's something fast I came up with: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pLsqhkg/1/)

Hope it helps :P

Comment: can you pls add your answer in fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Update provided. Enjoy :)

Comment: how can i get brandname?

Comment: pls check this https://jsfiddle.net/7pLsqhkg/3/ .if i want to add price for that particular model ?.i have added text box but when i submit it did't get value i am getting undefined

Comment: i am not getting brand name

Comment: You can get whatever you want. you just have to change the example code I have provided you as you wish. I don't know what exacly you would like to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101260/discussion-between-komal-and-hristo-enev).