# AngularJS Data Driven dropdown with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to create data driven cascading dropdown menu with Angularjs for my chart. 
Here is what I got so far [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/q46AMIf1aUeUi2i4VYqv?p=preview)

```
 Year:
<select id="YearSelector">
  <option ng-repeat="year in filterOptions.stores">{{year.year}}</option>
 </select>
Quarter:
<select id="QuarterSelector">
  <option ng-repeat="quarter in filterOptions.stores">{{quarter.quarter}}</option>
</select>
Channel:
<select id="channel">
  <option ng-repeat="channel in filterOptions.stores">{{channel.channel}}</option>
</select>
```

I understand in my select ng-repeat loop thru data and display each one of data to my selection menu. But I only want to **one time** for each data.

OUTPUT of dropdown menu should only have:

- **Year** dropdown  only: 2011, 2012
- **Quarter** dropdown only : 1 , 2
- **Channel**: Hypermarkets, Supermarkets

Comment: Do you mean you do not want your data to be updated?  you want it to be rendered only for the first time?

Comment: @RaviTeja I do want my data be updated, but since I will use this dropdown for filtering, I do not need "Year" 2011 appear on my dropdown more than one time. Same for quarter and channel. I hope this answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a filter which filter all the duplicate values

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          var key = item[keyname];
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
          }
      });

      return output;
   };
});
```

then in your html pass the parameter based on which do you want to filter

```
 <select id="YearSelector">
      <option ng-repeat="year in filterOptions.stores | unique: 'year'">{{year.year}}</option>
     </select>
    Quarter:
    <select id="QuarterSelector">
      <option ng-repeat="quarter in filterOptions.stores  | unique: 'quarter'">{{quarter.quarter}}</option>
    </select>
    Channel:
    <select id="channel">
      <option ng-repeat="channel in filterOptions.stores | unique: 'channel'">{{channel.channel}}</option>
    </select>
```

[AngularJs Remove duplicate elements in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well, to be honest I didn't think about searching "duplicate elements" Because I looked SO didn't find anything first

Answer (score 2):

Add [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) in your module as:

```
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
```

and use it in your html page as follows:

```
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in filterOptions.stores | groupBy: 'year'">
      {{key}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

I've done the year selector [in this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/yuzewobine/edit?html,js,output), hope it helps.

Dependency include:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

Comment: I do not why but this approach doesnt solver other dropdown. I try to follow the document you shared but still didnt worked

Comment: I modified the old JS Bin (same link) to work fine in your case. Using the same ng-controller for the three selectors "join" all filters together. If you use individual ng-controller (even though being the same "MainController") don't "join" the filters.

Comment: I see where I did wrong, I try to use "MainController" only in div to cover all select. Thanks for updating.