# ng-repeat nested HTML elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I like to use ng-repeat to print data to my html using Angularjs, i have to use unique and orderBy to avoid equals in year and month.

My data:

```
demo.data = 
  [
      { "year": 2016, "month": "November", "item": "November 01"}
    , { "year": 2016, "month": "November", "item": "November 02"}
    , { "year": 2016, "month": "January", "item": "January 01"}
    , { "year": 2015, "month": "December", "item": "December 01"}
  ];
```

Structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Year</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Month</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Item</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Ddc5PIYZAduOdzihnNO7?p=preview

Comment: I tried use ng-repeat, but `month` not is a array inside year.. This cause a problem with ng-repeat.

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: you should structure your data in your controller so that it matches what you want to display.  don't expect angular to know how to separate your data for you, and don't try to modify the data in the view.

Comment: `ng-repeat` must use for `array`, you just have an array is `data`, `year`, `month`, `item` are not array, you can't use `ng-repeat` for it.

Comment: @WorkMe, i know that, because that i liked to use only ng-repeat and not have a loop to create another object/array

Comment: you don't have nested data here, you have flat data.  you can't expect angular to turn your flat data into a nested display.

Comment: @Satya, @Claies; I add the example with my try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs Remove duplicate elements in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Claies, my idea is not create another array. I see this project https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/, but i dont know if its help.

Comment: This is not what the view is for.  If you don't want to structure the data correctly for the display you want, then this isn't the framework you should be using.  Don't make your users suffer because you don't want to organize your data properly.  Even if you manage to get this working with some sort of nested `ng-repeat` or series of filters, you are only **purposely** creating a performance issue for your app, unnecessarily.

Comment: @Claies, The number of iterations creating another array is bigger. Because i have to use ng-repeat creating or not another array.

Comment: no, it really isn't.  By trying to do it this way, you are asking angular to iterate through the array 3 times, and expecting it to filter out the things that you don't want to see on each loop.  and then, every time the data changes, **all** of the `ng-repeat` loops will be re-evaluated.  This is a performance nightmare, and a troubleshooting nightmare as well.  But good luck to you if you manage to find a way to make this work;  I can't make you do it the proper way.

Comment: I created a plunker that shows re-organizing the data in the controller, just in case you are interested;  I'm relatively positive this gives the output you are expecting:  http://plnkr.co/edit/c7XpXzTE0HeCgqRs2xpH?p=preview.  It uses the `(key, value)` syntax of `ng-repeat`, but demonstrates that the `key` and `value` names can be changed.

Comment: I created another fork with @codepills answer side by side with the code I wrote: http://plnkr.co/edit/k6AKZh29r9xCuLobHtcH?p=preview.   I encourage you to compare the difference in the HTML output between the two, and take note of the multitude of commented out rows in the `ng-if` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested items should only be included if they are in the same associated year and/or month. Adding `ng-if` conditions may be what you are looking for.

```
<body ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="y in demo.data | orderBy:'+year' | unique:'year'">
      <span ng-bind="y.year"></span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in demo.data | orderBy:'+month' | unique:'month'" ng-if="m.year == y.year">
          <span ng-bind="m.month"></span>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in demo.data | orderBy:'+item' | unique:'item'" ng-if="i.year == y.year && i.month == m.month">
              <span ng-bind="i.item"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code you've provided doesn't really make a lot of sense. Firstly the data wont be available on your page because you haven't added it to the scope. `demo.data` should look similar to `$scope.data`

ng-repeat is added to an element of your html. You can also add some 'keywords' such as orderBy and 'unique' to manipulate how the output is handled by angular.

Every element nested inside our repeating `<li>` will be repeated for each json object in `data`. This data will have it's year, month and item value written to the page where the `{{}}` enclosed values are. For instance `{{date.year}}` will display the date's year.

The `orderBy: 'year'` will arrange the dates by the year, and the `unique: 'item'` will ensure only one object with the item value is provided.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="date in data | unique:'item' | orderBy: 'year'">
    <span>{{date.year}}</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>{{date.month}}</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>{{date.item}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You need to do a little more research before asking a question. You've essentially just asked somebody to write you code for you. Even if you were to copy what I, or anyone else, gave you I don't think you yet have the understanding of angular to actually implement it. Please spend some more time learning angular and you'll find it's actually quite easy!

Here are some resources regarding ng-repeat to check out;

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

**EDIT:** You plunker example is very different from the kind of result I thought you were after.

Comment: this isn't going to produce the result the OP is expecting either, but that's mostly because the data isn't structured properly to be displayed in the manner expected.  `ng-repeat` can't make flat data into nested data.

Comment: Your code generate duplicates to year and month. About the data scope, i dont have use $scope, i recommend to read: https://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/

Comment: If you want a list of years, with months, then dates, you will need to create a data structure that consists of nested arrays. Then you will be able to nested ng-repeats on each of the levels you're after.