# angularjs remove duplicate values from ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a category dropdown list fetched from below JSON data. I have same category multiple times, For Ex: Computer

```
[
{ 
"title":"C Programming", 
"category":"Computer"
},
{ 
"title":"International Tax", 
"category":"Business"
},
{ 
"title":".net Programming", 
"category":"Computer"
}
//more data...
]
```

AngularJS:

```
function showSubjects($scope, $http)
{
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'js/subjects.json'}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.items= data; // response data 
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="showSubjects">
<select>
<option ng-repeat="subjects in items">{{subjects.category}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I want to display duplicate categories only once. Please give me some suggestions, how to acheive the required output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<option ng-repeat="subjects in items | unique:'category'">{{subjects.category}}</option>
```

Look here for more: [Unique & Stuff](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own function like below:

```
   <select name="cmpPro" ng-model="test3.Product" ng-options="q for q in productArray track by q">
    <option value="" >Plans</option>
</select>

productArray =[];
angular.forEach($scope.leadDetail, function(value,key){
var index = $scope.productArray.indexOf(value.Product);
if(index === -1)
{
    $scope.productArray.push(value.Product);
}
});
```

Comment: @UI_Dev : I am already using this code in 2 projects. May be it is not working for you. Answer given by Omri Aharon is good approach.