# AngularJS - repeating select options only once for each different value

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I have a HTML select box at the top of a page, the page shows a list of documents. The select box will have a list of available file extensions to filter the list of documents by. At the moment, I have:

```
<select data-ng-model="filterType">
    <option data-ng-repeat="item in docItems" value="{{item.extension}}">{{item.extension}}</option>
</select>
```

What the above code does is give me a list, for example:

- xls
- xls
- xls
- doc
- xls
- pdf
- pdf

But what I am wanting is to only show something like:

- xls
- pdf
- doc

So, it only shows one of each available values.

It's also important that the extension stays as the options value, as this is what I am using on my filter, like so:

```
 data-ng-repeat="docItem in docItems | filter:{extension: filterType}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the file name array and build a new array of just extensions. Do this in your controller.

Comment: "Do this in your controller" especially means: Don't create a filter to do that, because filters must not create a new `Array` on each run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **unique filter from AngularUI** (source code available here: AngularUI unique filter) and use it directly in the ng-options (or ng-repeat).

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" ng-options="place.category for place in places | unique:'category'">
    <option value="0>Default</option>
    // unique options from the categories
</select>
```

taken from [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)