# AngularJS: Discard duplicates element from an Json data which is from nodejs server sides rendered data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, duplicates

I am using ["itunes-search"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunes-search) module in nodejs and it is send the sends the search results as Json data. The Json data has a filed named "artistName" which has duplicates element I can see. but I want to print the "artistName" values discarding the duplicates instance. Means one value should be printed only one time. I have only included the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying with the bellowed code. But it is not working. Multiple elements of value are also printed.

```
<ul>
<li data-ng-repeat="data in response | orderBy:'artistName' | unique:'artistName' "> 
<b> {{data.artistName}} <b><br/>
</li>
</ul>
```

I will really appreciate him who will help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results

Comment: I did that but couldn't understand what to do.Where to add the functionalities. I added in some place of my js file but the whole project crushed after that:). Please help me.. @Jayram

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter  @Jayram

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your filter. Here is an example :

```
angular.module('app',[]).filter('unique', function() {
  return function(list, attribute) {
    var result= [];
    var keys = [];

    // Find duplicates
    angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
      if(keys.indexOf(item[attribute]) === -1) { // Not already present
          keys.push(item[attribute]);
          result.push(item);
      }
  });

  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says you need to have `unique` filter loaded in your angular app in order to use it. Angular could not find the filter and hence throwing the error. 
Here is the way you can fix that.

1. Save [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) as unique.js in your scripts and load it in HTML.
2. Add `'ui.filters'` to your dependencies in your app.

Comment: I new please can you tell me where to add the "ui.filters" dependencies