# Prevent duplicates in two different ng-repeats

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I am working on ng-table and facing an issue where I need to prevent duplicates from getting displayed via two different ng-repeats.

The `JSON` hierarchy is in this manner:

```
{
    "PageSize": 10,
    "TotalRecords": 54,
    "Users": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "Projects": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "Asean",
                    "Categories": [
                        {
                            "Id": 1,
                            "Name": "Category1",
                            "Markets": [
                                {
                                    "Id": 2,
                                    "Name": "Indonesia"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Id": 4,
                                    "Name": "Malaysia"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 2,
                            "Name": "Category2",
                            "Markets": [
                                {
                                    "Id": 2,
                                    "Name": "Indonesia"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Id": 4,
                                    "Name": "Malaysia"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Id": 7,
                                    "Name": "Japan"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the `HTML` for `ng-table` is:

```
<table class="table" ng-table="tableParams" id="relationTable">
    <tr ng-repeat="mapping in $data">
        <td class="text-left" data-title="'User'">{{mapping.FirstName}}</td>
        <td class="text-left" data-title="'Category'"><span ng-repeat="category in mapping.Projects[0].Categories track by $index">{{category.Name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span></td>
        <td class="text-left" data-title="'Market'"><span ng-repeat="category in mapping.Projects[0].Categories track by $index"><span ng-repeat="market in category.Markets track by $index">{{market.Name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

From above code, I generate a table where I am facing duplicates in 'Markets' column.
The table looks like:

```
+------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|_Name_|______Categories______|_____________________Markets_____________________|
+------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|_John_|_Category1,_Category2_|_Indonesia,_Malaysia,_Indonesia,_Malaysia,_Japan_|
+------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, here Indonesia and Malaysia are being displayed twice. Please suggest a method by which I can prevent the duplicates from being displayed in the 'Markets' column.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results

Comment: Use the `unique` filter on `ng-repeat`: `unique:"Name"`

Comment: what does your $data look like ? or the JSON you provided is $data ?

Comment: @Iceburg, thanks for a prompt response. Though I've already looked into AngularUI's unique. My problem remains the same as the `ngRepeat` with 'Market' values is nested under a 'categories' `ngRepeat`. This results in unique values in each `ngRepeat` and the duplicates are again rendered on the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done the needful for you by creating a very simple AngularJS filter .

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').filter('unique',function(){

  var sub=[];
  var flag=false;
  var result="";
  return function(input){

    for(var i=0;i<sub.length;i++){
      console.log('inside for loop');
      if(input==sub[i])
      {
        flag=true;
        break;
      }


    }
    if(flag){
      result="";
      flag=false;
      return result;
    }
    else{
      sub.push(input);
      result=input;
    }
    return result;

  };

});
```

you need to change a bit of your HTML code , replace `{{market.Name}}` with `{{market.Name | unique }}`

[here is the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YwjN6C1Qqx7VGjMUvfng?p=preview)

Comment: Man! You are just awesome. Instead of comparing `Name`, can we do this on `ID`?

Comment: yes why not !  All you need to do is to change `{{market.Name | unique }}` to `{{market.Id | unique}}`

Comment: I want to display `Name` and pass `Id`. Should it be like `{{market.Name | unique:marketId}}`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YwjN6C1Qqx7VGjMUvfng?p=preview  check this out . In this i am passing `market.Id` and displaying `market.Name` using `ng-show` on the basis of boolean value returned by 'unique' filter .

Answer (score 0):

Use,
 `<span ng-repeat="market in category.Markets track by $index | unique:'Name'">{{market.Name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>`

(source code : [unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js))

Comment: This won't solve the problem. If you look at the JSON, one `ngRepeat` over 'Markets' won't bring the duplicates. It'll be the second ngRepeat which will bring the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix Try something with this. later i will add more to this. but i couldn't test this. its up to you.
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bvsvzrr5/49/)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'id'"></div>

app.filter('unique', function() {
return function(collection, keyname) {
  var output = [], 
      keys = [];

  angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          keys.push(key);
          output.push(item);
      }
  });
  return output;
 };
});
```

Comment: This works on duplicates in one array. I'm talking about finding duplicates in two different arrays.