# 'ng-repeat' How to get the `unique` values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Using an array, I am trying to filter and show the `unique` information in the list. For that I use the `angular` inbuild `filter` method.

But I am getting error.

Here is my try (I am filtering by `SubProjectName`)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="project in projectNames | unique: 'SubProjectName' ">
        {project.SubProjectName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sx3u1ukH9752oR1Jfx6R)

Comment: Angular's built in filter does not have a `unique` method.

Comment: is it so.. then what would be the way to get it done? any one suggest me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't include a `unique` filter by default. You can use the one from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). Just include the JavaScript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

and include the dependeny in your app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

Your code should work right away! I edited your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhIMSfRFh5GwZ3SN5trs?p=preview) so it works.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for an answer like this

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.projectNames=projects
  $scope.Id = "1";
  $scope.SubProjectName="Retail Building";

})
.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(projects, subProjectName) {
    var newprojects =[];
    projects.forEach(function(project){
      if(project.SubProjectName === subProjectName)
        newprojects.push(project);
    });
    return newprojects;
  };
});
```

---

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projectNames | unique:SubProjectName">{{project.SubProjectName}}</li>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/x8HSgR3JlTdpI0VrLg6W)

Comment: It is nice to do this instead of adding another package to do the same functionality

Answer (score 3):

The `unique` filter you are probably attempting to use comes from AngularUI, so you need to include it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

and add it as module dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.filters']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your plunkr as http://plnkr.co/edit/sx3u1ukH9752oR1Jfx6R?p=preview
added filter dependency

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular.filter']);
```

Hope this may help you