# How to have a validation between radio buttons which are dynamically created in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a dynamic radio buttons and checkboxes .But when enter their labels how can we have a validation so that no name is repeated again for next controls respectively

```
<span style="padding-left: 20px" ng-repeat="r in field.rbtn track by $index | unique:'r.radioname'" >
    <input type="radio"  id="radio_{{$index}}">{{r.radioname}}
</span>
```

For this I have used like this..but it does not displaying the values only the label is displayed but under it ,no radio button with its name is not displaying

Comment: I suggest you create a jsfiddle of what's happening

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are using **ng-repeat** for dynamically generating checkboxes.

You can use the [Angular unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) for removing duplicates in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you please say how to use it

Comment: Just have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results