# remove double results value from forEach (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, filter

there is this thing who i am not figuring out,
i have a controller that return me an array of products propriety, that populate a  field, so far i have done this:

```
     $scope.categoryForFilter=[];
//product load
ProductService.listProducts().then(function(data) {
    $scope.products = {
        count: data.count,
        list: data.aaData,
        length: data.aaData.length
    };
    $scope.products.list.forEach(function (element) {
            $scope.categoryForFilter.push({"id": element.category.id, "label": element.category.label})
    });
});
```

but in this way i have multiple element.category.label in the options field that in my view is the following:

```
<select ng-model="categoryForFilter" ng-options="cat.label for cat in categoryForFilter" st-search="cat.label">
                        <option></option>
</select>
```

so how can i filter the results who have the same value in the array? anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unique` filter, which is part of [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).

You can also use this filter using lodash:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function (arr, field) {
        return _.uniq(arr, function(a) { return a[field]; });
    };
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22517370/4550627)

Answer (score 1):

There is a real easy way to this by using lib like lodash with the function "uniq":

```
$scope.categoryForFilterWithUniqLabel = _.uniq($scope.categoryForFilter, 'label');
```