# Filtering out duplicate artist names in itunes search API response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

In my angular app, after making a jsonp request to the search API, specifying that I want 25 results in the response object, I'm getting a lot of tracks with duplicate `artistId` and hence `artistName`. I want to keep the first object in the array, and delete the following repeated objects with the same `artistID` attributes. Can I tell the API to return only unique values of `artistID`? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results) but the accepted answer seems dated.

Comment: In what way is it dated? Have you tried it, I think you might have some success with it.

Comment: The `unique` filter you see in the anwser you linked is available in angular-filter : https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: @Lauromine I'm getting this error when I try to inject `'ui.filters'` into the app module.

Comment: I've tried it, and it's not filtering out the results.

Comment: it was a problem with the `property` I was specifying, in the filter. It's working now.