# AngularJS unique filter on multiple values ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, unique

How can I make sure a complete row is unique in AngularJS?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="service in services" >
```

I'm aware of the existing unique filter [discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results) However this only explains how to unique filter over one column. I would like to do it for on multiple columns. For example:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="service in services | unique:['category','type','quantity'] >
```

Comment: what is expected behavior? Can interpret this several ways

Comment: If you want the combination of *all* columns in each row to be unique, then you can use `unique` without any arguments, like `ng-repeat="service in services | unique"`, in which case the entire object will be tested for (deep) equality. If you want just a subset, the AngularUI filter doesn't support that, but you can write your own.

Comment: There's plenty of examples of filtering by one key, but most of the time you need multiple. Hoping to draw some attention to this to get a viable answer.