# Filter unique date values from JSON

Tags: angularjs

I am using unique filter to display JSON data. 
This is my JSON data:

```
data= [
        {
            itemId: "100",
            name: "x001",
            date: "2016-01-16T16:17:38.928-05:00"
        },      
        {
            itemId: "102",
            name: "x002",
            date: "2016-01-16T16:05:20.928-05:00"
        },      
        {
            itemId: "103",
            name: "x003",
            date: "2016-01-15T10:10:01.715-05:00"
        },      
        {
            itemId: "104",
            name: "x004",
            date: "2016-01-15T12:15:01.715-05:00"
        },      
        {
            itemId: "105",
            name: "x005",
            date: "2016-01-14T12:15:25.928-05:00"
        }
]
```

I am trying to display itemswith no repeated date, so that my output will be:
x001
x003
x005
How do I use unique filter which filters only date value (not consider Time  stamp in date field)
here is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result | unique:'date'">
   {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `momentjs` by chance? (Makes working with dates easier in JS)

Comment: no I am not using that

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results#comment23247377_15941016)

Basically says: 
you must include filters as an additional reference in your module angular.module('yourModule', ['ui', 'ui.filters']);