# Angularjs: Ng-repeat and unique filter in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a set of data like this

```
$scope.students = [
   { name:"John", courses:["Math", "Physics", "Chemistry"] },
   { name:"Paul", courses:["Economics", "Math", "Sociology"] }
]
```

I would like a way to filter using angular-filter so that I can get a list of all the subjects without repetition.
I've been trying to use unique filter, but I cannot get it to work since  I try to iterate like

```
<ul ng-repeat="student in students">
   <li ng-repeat="x in student.courses | unique:courses"></li>
       {{x}}
</ul>
```

My desired output of the first ng-repeat would be an array like this:

```
["Math", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Economics", "Sociology"]
```

so I could iterate through it in the second one.

I have achieved this throught making a new scope with just the desired array, but then I cannot bind it properly, so I would like to achieve it through filtering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: You can use the library: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js. Btw, `ng-repeat` must be used exclusively in the `<li>` tag and not the `<ul>`.

Comment: @Martin, it is not the same case, as I unique:courses doesn't work if courses refers to an array

Comment: @developer033, yes, that's exactly what I want to use, but I don't know how to achieve that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend you using the libraries [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for this kind of problems. Learning to master these has helped me a lot!

Of course, you can create your own angular filter using one of them. The method you would like to use is union:

```
_.union(_.flatten(_($scope.students).pluck("courses")))
```

I use pluck to get out the courses arrays from the studens object, then I flatten the result (to get rid of the array that it comes nested in), and then i use union to get each subject only once.

Comment: I didn't know that I could easily create my own custom filter. This make my day :)

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement actually is to:

> ...get a list of all the subjects without repetition.

Then I would make a separate array for subjects:

```
$scope.courses = [];

// There are many ways to do skin this cat... (prograde does have a point!)
$scope.students.forEach(function(student) {
  student.courses.forEach(function(course) {
    if ( $scope.courses.indexOf(course) === -1 ) {
      $scope.courses.push(course);
    }
  })
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="course in courses">
    {{ course }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And if the students change I would recreate the courses-array.

But it sounds as if you are trying to do something else.

> But it doesn't give the desired output.

*It would help if you tell us what that desired output is!*

http://plnkr.co/edit/bZNjIEFznvuyTU3zxAp1?p=preview

Comment: I edited the question. The output with your solution is correct, but I don't want to have a separate scope for this as later I cannot bind it to the other one through ng-model.