# AngularJs Remove duplicate records in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing an ionic application which will be able to be used as a timetable-like application. I am trying to pull in data using this line of code in an ng-repeat

```
<ion-item ng-show="item.Location" ng-repeat="item in test | filter: {Day: 'Fri'}>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
        <td>
        Course
        </td>
        <td>{{item.Course}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>
         Tutor
        </td>
        <td>{{item.Staff_Name}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>
        Campus
        </td>
        <td>{{item.Campus}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</ion-item>
```

Is there anyway in which I can use a this code and remove a record if all columns of that record match? Meaning that if the record has an exact duplicate, it will only display one?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: show us your $scope.test... data

Comment: @Thalaivar the $scope.test is just a timetable from a student, but some have came through as duplicates, they cannot be unique by only one record, they will be to be duplicates within all columns.

Comment: Can you create a mock data of the same...

Comment: @Thalaivar
StudentID, 
Course,
Module,
Activity_Start_Time,
Activity_EndTime,
Activity_Date,
Activity_Type,
Day,
Campus,
Location,
Staff_Name,
Timetabled_Hours.
Above are the list of fields which will be saved under each lesson a student will have

Comment: You should be using the `unique` modifier to the filter. It's pretty simple to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/n7zcg/

Comment: How do I use the unique modifier to check all fields?

Comment: Hm, in that case you  may have to make your own filter to perform that task and return the results