# how to avoid duplicate items with ng-repeat and drop in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can you advice me the right sole of some issue?
I have next situation:

1.I load list of items from server and list it with ng-repeat in container here:

```
<div layout="column" id={{vm.folderId}}container flex layout-align="start center" class='container' dragula='"first-bag"'>
   <div id={{item.id}}child class="md-whiteframe-5dp capitalize itemsInList" layout="column"  ng-repeat="item in vm.workItems | filter:search">
      <div layout="column" flex >
         <div class="workItemName">{{vm.getWorkItemName(item.metadata)}}</div>
         <div class="workItemDescription">{{vm.getWorkItemDescription(item.metadata)}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So lets say we have listed next list:

```
item_1
item_2
item_3
item_4
```

than I drop another element into this container, ITEM_5.
After I've droped server gives me new list: item_1 -
    item_2 -
    item_3 -
    item_4 -
    item_5
and I update my `vm.workItems` here:

```
if (data.ok) {
    if (data.content.items.length != vm.workItems.length) {
        vm.workItems = data.content.items; //from server
        SharedDataService.setLastUpdateTimeStamp(SharedDataService.getNewUpdateTimeStamp());
    }
}
```

After when it ng-repeat fresh items it also view droped element in list.So in the end I have:

```
item_1 //ng-repeated
item_2 //ng-repeated
item_3 //ng-repeated
item_4 //ng-repeated
item_5 //ng-repeated
item_5 //droped element
```

How to avoid this? is there some normal solving?

update. I drop element ,when it's droped I make request to server to ad new item to list:

```
  $scope.$on('first-bag.drop', function (e, el, container) {
        var elementId = parseInt(el[0].id);
        var newContainerId = parseInt(container[0].id);
        var newPrevElementId;
        var newPrevElement = document.getElementById(el[0].id).previousElementSibling;

        if(newPrevElement) {
            newPrevElementId = parseInt(newPrevElement.getAttribute('id'));
        } else  if(!newPrevElement)  {
            newPrevElementId = newContainerId;
        }

        if(exContainerId != newContainerId) {
            WebSocketService.addItem(elementId, exContainerId,
}
}
```

Comment: Found another similar question asked. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24490995/5726639](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24490995/5726639). This might help you. [Angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
ng-repeat="item in vm.workItems track by item.id | filter:search"
```

If each item has a unique ID(or something unique property), and if you use `track by` ID, then even if server returns previous items with a new item added to it DOM will not get re-rendered, only new item will be added to the DOM.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9rqEFSb1QJA2JC41rcNW?p=preview) (take a look at console)

`ng-repeat` adds `$$hashkey` property to **each** object when it repeats through a list of objects.

When your server returns the new data, though there are already existing objects, since, the new data(each object) does not contain `$$hashkey` property in it, `ng-repeat` re-renders then thinking they are new objects.

If you use `track by ID` then `ng-repeat` does not add a `$$hashkey` property, it keeps track of each item using `ID`. So, even if server returns same data again, since, ID's matches, `ng-repeat` does not repeat them. If there are new ID's then it renders then to the DOM.

Take a look at this blog [post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm).

Comment: this should do i guess?   

    ng-repeat="item in vm.workItems track by index"

Comment: @AmitKarnik I am not 100% sure, but  `track by $index` uses position of an object in the array. If the same data comes from server again with different order then there might be some problems. But, with ID you can always be sure no matter which order they come.

Comment: I'll try to use it. hope will not get extra DOM element

Comment: sorry missed out on '$' , thanks for the clarification.

Comment: still renders extra dom :( 
I used: 
  
     <div class="md-whiteframe-1dp capitalize itemsInList" layout="column"  ng-repeat="item in vm.workItems track by item.id" id={{item.id}}child >

Comment: You said your are dropping an element. How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you doing in `$scope.$on` function and show related HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
let data = data.content.items;
let temp = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
    if (temp.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    temp.push(item);
  }
});
vm.workItems = temp;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the same.It lists received items via ng-repeat before droped DOM element. but thank  you for trying.