# Angular Js - Avoid repetition in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing the system for Hotel POS solution. I want to fetch all the current orders and show the table number of orders only once.

But the table number is repeating for all the orders
I have written following code :

```
<span ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentOrder'  ng-if='orders.custId==ctrl.person" + scope.divId + ".selected.cust_id && orders.orderType=="+scope.orderType+"'>Table No. : {{orders.tableNumber}}</span>
```

and I want output as :

```
Table No. : 9
```

but I am getting

```
Table No. : 9Table No. : 9Table No. : 9Table No. : 9Table No. : 9Table No. : 9Table No. : 9
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is $index available with ng-repeat you can make condition based on $index and if your matched index found then only you can print table number.

Comment: Did you try using `unique` filter?. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941016/4331291) answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `track by`:
`ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentOrder track by orders.tableNumber'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentOrder track by $index'  ng-if='orders.custId==ctrl.person" + scope.divId + ".selected.cust_id && orders.orderType=="+scope.orderType+"'>Table No. : {{orders.tableNumber}}</span>
```