# How to use unique value in custom filter using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

How to get unique value using Angular JS?

I want to get unique name with recent modified Date

here in this code Now I create a custom filter in my controller, that can iterate over the items in my ng-repeat and return only the items that meet certain criteria

This is my JS Code

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('lsnPlanLog', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var filtered = [];

        angular.forEach(items, function(el) {
          if(el.modifiedBy && el.modifiedOn) {
        el.meta.createdBy.name = el.meta.modifiedBy.name;
        el.meta.createdBy.id = el.meta.modifiedBy.id;
        el.createdOn = el.modifiedOn;
          }
        });

        for(var i = 1; i < items.length; ){
          if(items[i-1].meta.createdBy.id == items[i].meta.createdBy.id){
        items.splice(i, 1);
          } else {
              i++;
          }
        }
    return items;
  }
});

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

$scope.lsnPlanDailysLog = [
     {
     "id":"588f6347d991391aeae10c5b",
     "createdOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:59 AM",
     "createdBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:59 AM",
     "meta":{
        "id":"588f6347d991391aeae10c5b",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Sachin Tendulakar",
           "id":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Sachin Tendulakar",
           "id":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"588f73b7d991391aeae10c5c",
     "createdOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "createdBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "meta":{
        "id":"588f73b7d991391aeae10c5c",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"588f7778d991391aeae10c5d",
     "createdOn":"04-Feb-2017 01:03 AM",
     "createdBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedOn":"04-Feb-2017 01:03 AM",
     "meta":{
        "id":"588f7778d991391aeae10c5d",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"58938605d991390e8040cd4b",
     "createdOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "createdBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "meta":{
        "id":"58938605d991390e8040cd4b",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"5893861cd991390e8040cd4c",
     "createdOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "createdBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedBy":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1",
     "modifiedOn":"03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM",
     "meta":{
        "id":"5893861cd991390e8040cd4c",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Rahul Dravid",
           "id":"56b9e986b3cb1f000125c4d1"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"5893862ed991390e8040cd4d",
     "createdOn":"04-Feb-2017 01:00 AM",
     "createdBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "modifiedOn":"04-Feb-2017 01:00 AM",
     "meta":{
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Sachin Tendulakar",
           "id":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf"
        },
        "modifiedBy":{
           "name":"Sachin Tendulakar",
           "id":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf"
        }
     }
      },
      {
     "id":"5894dacdd991390e8040cd4e",
     "createdOn":"04-Feb-2017 01:02 AM",
     "createdBy":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf",
     "meta":{
        "id":"5894dacdd991390e8040cd4e",
        "createdBy":{
           "name":"Sachin Tendulakar",
           "id":"534ceeaae4b0aeb8292ed6cf"
        }
     }
      }
]

})



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped"" style="width: 100%;" ng-if="lsnPlanDailysLog!=undefined && lsnPlanDailysLog.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: teal;width: 10%;">#</th>
            <th style="color: teal;width: 20%;text-align: center;">Type</th>
            <th style="color: teal;width: 20%;text-align: center;">Last updated by</th>
            <th style="color: teal;width: 20%;text-align: center;">Last updated date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="eachLsnPlanDailyLog in lsnPlanDailysLog | orderBy:['-createdOn','-modifiedOn'] | lsnPlanLog">
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td style="width: 20%;text-align: center;">LSN Plan Delivery</td>
            <td style="width: 20%;text-align: center;">{{eachLsnPlanDailyLog.meta.createdBy.name}}</td>
            <td style="width: 20%;text-align: center;">{{eachLsnPlanDailyLog.createdOn}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my output for getting above code

```
#      Type             Last updated by     Last updated date

1   LSN Plan Delivery   Rahul Dravid            04-Feb-2017 01:03 AM

2   LSN Plan Delivery   Sachin Tendulakar   04-Feb-2017 01:02 AM

3   LSN Plan Delivery   Rahul Dravid            03-Feb-2017 12:58 AM
```

My expected output is below one

```
#      Type             Last updated by     Last updated date

1   LSN Plan Delivery   Rahul Dravid            04-Feb-2017 01:03 AM

2   LSN Plan Delivery   Sachin Tendulakar   04-Feb-2017 01:02 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you need order by `createdBy` before  compare:

```
 items[i-1].meta.createdBy.id == items[i].meta.createdBy.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `orderBy` to get the listing ordered by last modified time, like you're already doing, and then use some type of unique filter, such as [this angular ui filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js), or take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results) for some more ideas and functions for uniqueness. So, it might look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="eachLsnPlanDailyLog in lsnPlanDailysLog | orderBy:['-createdOn','-modifiedOn'] | unique:'modifiedBy'">
             <!-- Your content -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```