# How to debug Unique not displaying properly in AngularUI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ui-utils

**Include**

```
<script src="/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/app.js"></script>
```

**myApp**

```
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui'], function($interpolateProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

---

If I do this

```
<p>[[ skills  ]]</p>
```

I got this

`[{"id":17,"type":"Content Management","name":"NPM","value":"84","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 14:00:26","updated_at":"2017-03-09 15:25:50"},{"id":16,"type":"Content Management","name":"Composer ","value":"80","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 14:00:14","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:16:54"},{"id":15,"type":"Framework","name":"AngularJS","value":"73","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:59:00","updated_at":"2017-03-08 13:59:30"},{"id":14,"type":"Content Management","name":"RequireJS","value":"65","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:58:06","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:17:10"},{"id":9,"type":"Content Management","name":"Bower","value":"70","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:53","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:17:02"},{"id":8,"type":"Web Scaffolding","name":"Yeoman","value":"50","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:43","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:09:57"},{"id":7,"type":"Build System","name":"Gulp","value":"90","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:18","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:07:20"},{"id":6,"type":"Development Environment","name":"Docker","value":"60","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:59","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:38"},{"id":5,"type":"Development Environment","name":"Vagrant","value":"70","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:46","updated_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:46"},{"id":3,"type":"Build System","name":"Grunt ","value":"88","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:49:40","updated_at":"2017-03-09 12:01:04"},{"id":2,"type":"Server Management","name":"Linux","value":"87","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:45:34","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:27"},{"id":1,"type":"Framework","name":"Laravel 5","value":"95","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:24:16","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:14"}]`

---

If I do this

**`<p ng-repeat="skill in skills ">[[ skill.type  ]]</p>`**

I got

```
Content Management

Content Management

Framework

Content Management

Content Management

Web Scaffolding

Build System

Development Environment

Development Environment

Build System

Server Management

Framework
```

Now, I tried this

**`<p ng-repeat="skill in skills | unique: 'skill.type'  ">[[ skill.type  ]]</p>`**

I got this

```
Content Management
```

What did I do  wrong ? Why only 1 printing out ?

I expected to get something like this

```
Content Management

Framework

Web Scaffolding

Build System

Development Environment

Server Management
```

Comment: try angular-filter https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: @MMK : I've tried your suggestion and updated my post.

Comment: Do you know what I did wrong ?

Comment: <p ng-repeat="skill in skills |  groupBy:'skill.type' | unique: 'skill.type' "> {{ skill.type }}</p>

Comment: @MMK : I update my post. I don't get error anymore. I am close. I use angular UI. But I should get more results. Can you please help take a look my syntax ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705180/unknown-provider-uniquefilterprovider-uniquefilter)

Answer (score 1):

There is no groupBy built into AngularJS. You can wrap the lodash one if you don't feel like writing one yourself. In this case you could just use the _.uniq function (unless you're really grouping, not just selecting unique entries).

EDIT: Lodash is worth installing for the whole Swiss army knife of array of utilities it provides. You can filter for unique skill.type by something like
      $scope.uniqueSkills = _.uniqBy($scope.skills, 'type');

Then in the view, use "ng-repeat=skill in uniqueSkills | orderBy: type"

There are a few ways to do this. You could also create a filter which calls on the lodash function, but this will do the trick.

Comment: No other suggestions  ?

Comment: I updated my post. I don't get errors anymore. I am close. I use angular UI. But I should get more results. Can you please help take a look my syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your html like this and it works:

```
      <div>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items|unique: 'type'">{{item.type}}</li>
      </div>
```

Please take a look at the plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3oYKQcGr7tn8FSEGAk69?p=preview). The key is to specify the property by which you want uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

```
I got this working,
```

```js
var app = angular.module('demoapp', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.skills=[{"id":17,"type":"Content Management","name":"NPM","value":"84","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 14:00:26","updated_at":"2017-03-09 15:25:50"},{"id":16,"type":"Content Management","name":"Composer ","value":"80","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 14:00:14","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:16:54"},{"id":15,"type":"Framework","name":"AngularJS","value":"73","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:59:00","updated_at":"2017-03-08 13:59:30"},{"id":14,"type":"Content Management","name":"RequireJS","value":"65","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:58:06","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:17:10"},{"id":9,"type":"Content Management","name":"Bower","value":"70","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:53","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:17:02"},{"id":8,"type":"Web Scaffolding","name":"Yeoman","value":"50","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:43","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:09:57"},{"id":7,"type":"Build System","name":"Gulp","value":"90","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:54:18","updated_at":"2017-03-09 13:07:20"},{"id":6,"type":"Development Environment","name":"Docker","value":"60","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:59","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:38"},{"id":5,"type":"Development Environment","name":"Vagrant","value":"70","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:46","updated_at":"2017-03-08 13:53:46"},{"id":3,"type":"Build System","name":"Grunt ","value":"88","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:49:40","updated_at":"2017-03-09 12:01:04"},{"id":2,"type":"Server Management","name":"Linux","value":"87","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:45:34","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:27"},{"id":1,"type":"Framework","name":"Laravel 5","value":"95","description":null,"img_path":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 13:24:16","updated_at":"2017-03-09 14:15:14"}];
});

app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(collection, primaryKey) { //no need for secondary key
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];
          var splitKeys = primaryKey.split('.'); //split by period


      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            var key = {};
            angular.copy(item, key);
            for(var i=0; i<splitKeys.length; i++){
                key = key[splitKeys[i]];    //the beauty of loosely typed js :)
            }

            if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
            }
      });

      return output;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  
          <div ng-app="demoapp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="item in skills | unique:'type'">{{item.type}}</li>
          </div>
```

Comment: How comes I don't see you inject the `[ui]` in here `var app = angular.module('demoapp', []);` ? Did you even use angular UI ?

Comment: I am not using it. but the the output you want is there.

Comment: So `| unique:'type'` is the answer ? Is it come with angularJS ?

Comment: It is extended method which I have added, `app.filter('unique', function() {
` note this is customized.