# Removing Duplicate in Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, duplicates

The data in `$scope.filteredShows` looks like this:

```
[{"id":19,"show_name":"The Walking Dead","show_type":"Series","show_date":"Sun, Feb 26 2017","orig_date":"2017-02-26","season":"7","ep_val":"11","episode":"Season 7, Episode 11","watched":false},

{"id":20,"show_name":"The Walking Dead","show_type":"Series","show_date":"Sun, Mar 5 2017","orig_date":"2017-03-05","season":"7","ep_val":"12","episode":"Season 7, Episode 12","watched":false},

{"id":21,"show_name":"The Walking Dead","show_type":"Series","show_date":"Sun, Mar 12 2017","orig_date":"2017-03-12","season":"7","ep_val":"13","episode":"Season 7, Episode 13","watched":false},

{"id":22,"show_name":"The Walking Dead","show_type":"Series","show_date":"Sun, Mar 19 2017","orig_date":"2017-03-19","season":"7","ep_val":"14","episode":"Season 7, Episode 14","watched":false}]
```

I am using this data to populate a `select` class using `ng-options`:

```
ng-options='show.show_name for show in filteredShows track by show.id'
```

But there are more than one 'The Walking Dead' episode listed therefore it lists 'The Walking Dead' on the dropdown 4 times. How do I go about removing duplicates in this array?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/3931488).

Comment: Are you using angular-ui?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply construct a new array in scope that only includes the relevant data points... You can do:

```
const tmp = {} //Tmp var to store show_name's
$scope.showsOnly = $scope.filteredShows.filter(s => 
    tmp[s.show_name]?0:(tmp[s.show_name] = 1)
)
```

This filters all show by name (and only allows one instance of a `show_name`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
ng-options='show.show_name for show in filteredShows track by show.show_name'
```

or you can try _.uniq() method of underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lodash you can do this with _.uniqBy():

```
_.uniqBy(data ,"show_name")
```

for more info :https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `groupBy` filter in ng-repeat.

```
ng-options="show.show_name for show in filteredShows track by show.id | groupBy: 'show_name'"
```