# How to check duplicate entries while adding to javascript object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have this AngularJS service.

```
demoService.getDemoData($scope.countEP).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.allEditorPicks.push(data[i]);
                }
            });
```

In this case,allEditorPicks is an array i have defined at the top of the code as follows.

> $scope.allEditorPicks = [];

Here's the problem, when I'm using this array and printing these data, the array has same items. Duplicating. So I need a way to check existing items and stop adding them in that allEditorPicks array. We need to do this inside the for loop. I tried adding another loop inside the for loop and read the allEditorPicks array and check. But that doesn't work too.

```
demoService.getDemoData($scope.countEP).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.allEditorPicks.length; j++) {
                        if ($scope.allEditorPicks[j].itemName == data[i].itemName) {
                            console.log("Item Exists")
                        } else {
                            $scope.allEditorPicks.push(data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the solution I tried. My browser got freezes and stopped working when I run this code. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Answer (score 0):

first, sort the array by `itemName` and then remove the duplicates according to the order.

```
data = data.sort(function(a,b){
 return a.itemName - b.itemName;
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if(data[i].itemName === data[i++].itemName){
       console.log("Item Exists");
   }else {
        $scope.allEditorPicks.push(data[i]);
   }           
}
```

Comment: Hi bro, sorting is better. Bit the sorting code you gave me is not working. Can you please check that ? it's a great help

Comment: can you post the full json

Comment: { videocategory : 2,
videoid : 2134
videotitle : "Science&Tech 001" }

Comment: This is the ob. A simple one

Comment: post a json with `itemName` property

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
demoService.getDemoData($scope.countEP).then(function (data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   let found = $scope.allEditorPicks.find(elt => {
      return elt.itemName === data[i].itemName;
   });
   if(!found){
      $scope.allEditorPicks.push(data[i]);
   }
  }
})
```