# Select tag ng-model returns an undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel

I have a select tag in my html code like this:

```
<select ng-model="brandList" name="brandList"  style="width:110px;" >
    <option value="" selected>---Please select---</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in brandnameList | unique:'brandname'" value="{{item.brandname}}" style="width:50px;"> {{item.brandname}}</option>

</select>
```

The values in my select was fetched from the database via API and the code goes like this.

```
adminService.getbrandnameList()
                .then(function(data){
                    $scope.brandnameList = data.data;
                    $scope.brandn=data.data[0].brandname;

            });
```

I have another function that needs the selected value on the select tag

```
    $scope.ExportmodalAdmin = function () {
            alert(  $scope.brandList )
    }
```

But the model for the select which is $scope.brandList returns an undefined value. How can I fix this? I need the value from the select tag to be passed on the function.

Comment: post JSON example you get from `adminService.getbrandnameList()`

Comment: Your code is correct but your missing to define the variable $scope.brandList = {}; before the method ExportmodalAdmin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: could you please post plunker of your code

Comment: @Chandru, I defined the variable $scope.brandList ={} before method exportmodalAdmin but it returns {Object object} response

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have defined the variable brandList in your controller.

```
$scope.brandList = {};
```

Also, Change your ng-repeat statement as below:

```
 <select ng-model="brandList" name="brandList" ng-options="item.brandname for item in brandnameList" style="width:110px;" ng-change="alertChange()" >
    <option value="" selected>---Please select---</option>
</select>
```

Controller code to check change:

```
$scope.alertChange = function(){
    alert($scope.brandList.brandname);
  };
```

look at plunker reference here [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/WwZCSBUfjIr9yCrWmdgE?p=preview)

Comment: I defined the variable brandList in my controller but it returns {object |object} value. When I change my ng-repeat statement, the dropdown select has no values listed on it

Comment: Can you post the result of getbrandnameList() function

Comment: the result of the getbrandnameList() function is like this
  [
     {
        "brandname": "Aromatherapy Associates"
     },
    {
        "brandname": "ST.Tropez"
    },
    {
        "brandname": "Sampar"
    },
    {
        "brandname": "Jack Black"
    },
    {
        "brandname": "CeraVe"
    }
]

Comment: I have updated the ng-repeat section. Test it and let me know

Comment: the values still does not show on the dropdown list

Comment: I have updated my answer with the working plunker link. kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155220/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-kalyan).