# How to get unique element in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm having problems on filtering an array of String with ng-options

Assuming I have an array of this type

```
$scope.params.output = ["A","B","A","B","A","B"];
```

and an HTML of this type:

```
ng-options="item as item for item in params.output | unique : 'item'"
```

my select renders all the array, without filtering it, where did i get wrong?

Comment: Did you include relevant lib as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941016/492258)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#uniq

Comment: I think you should add unique filter on params.output

Comment: It's simple, using `index` you can sort your array. See this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60128/removing-duplicates-from-an-array-quickly You can create filter and use that for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add [unique.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) in your code.Copy this js and place it in seperate js file and attach it to your code

Answer (score 0):

use this **filter**. it will work.

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(collection, keyname) {
        var output = [], 
        keys = [];

        angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            var key = item[keyname];
            if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                output.push(item);
            }
        });

        return output;
    };
});
```

**Template**:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'id'"></div>
```

Comment: this code will work for array of object and you want to get unique object. for array of string there is a minor modification in code.