# How to show unique values once using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'm trying to only show items from a database once, `link.DocCategory` and `link.DocSubCategory`. Using `| unique: 'DocCategory'` did not give me my expected result as it actually displays `DocCategory` once but also removes other instances that share the same `DocCategory`. I'd like to show the `DocCategory` once with it's related `DocSubCategory` items showing once with their related `URL` info showing.

Here is my JSON structure:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "URL": {
        "Description": "Capabilities",
        "Url": "https://www.test.com"
      },
      "Comments": null,
      "DocCategory": "The LIFE Links",
      "DocSubCategory": "The Sales Program",
      "Order0": 1,
      "Description": "<div class=\"ExternalClass7655A65DDC5041F9B50820BD16C94366\"><p>\u200bThis is a link to show all of the capabilities that we have to offer.</p></div>",
      "Name": "Capabilities",
      "ID": 1
    }, {
      "URL": {
        "Description": "Abilities",
        "Url": "https://www.test2.com"
      },
      "Comments": null,
      "DocCategory": "The LIFE Links",
      "DocSubCategory": "The Sales Program",
      "Order0": 1,
      "Description": "<div class=\"ExternalClass7655A65DDC5041F9B50820BD16C94366\"><p>\u200bThis is a link to show all of the abilities that we have to offer.</p></div>",
      "Name": "Capabilities",
      "ID": 1
    }
  ]}
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat= "link in links | unique:'DocCategory'">
          <h1 class="category">{{link.DocCategory}}<h1>
          <h2 class="subcategory"><span class="subcatspan">{{link.DocSubCategory}}</span></h2>
          <a class="links" href={{link.URL.Url}} target="_blank">{{link.URL.Description}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I am trying to hide duplicate items in the view, not remove them altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: you want to group by?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I want to group by DocCategory. I’m ordering by `Order0` from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'grouBy' with angular-filter

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('test',['angular.filter'])
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.data= {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "URL": {
        "Description": "Capabilities",
        "Url": "https://www.test.com"
      },
      "Comments": null,
      "DocCategory": "The LIFE Links",
      "DocSubCategory": "The Sales Program",
      "Order0": 1,
      "Description": "first",
      "Name": "Capabilities",
      "ID": 1
    }, {
      "URL": {
        "Description": "Abilities",
        "Url": "https://www.test2.com"
      },
      "Comments": null,
      "DocCategory": "The LIFE Links",
      "DocSubCategory": "The Sales Program",
      "Order0": 1,
      "Description": "<div class=\"ExternalClass7655A65DDC5041F9B50820BD16C94366\"><p>\u200bThis is a link to show all of the abilities that we have to offer.</p></div>",
      "Name": "Capabilities",
      "ID": 1
    }
  ]}
};
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.16/angular-filter.js" > </script>

<body ng-app='test' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="log in data.d.results | groupBy: 'DocCategory'">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DocSubCategory</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in log" >
                        <td>{{item.DocSubCategory }}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```