# Duplicate Value in Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

enter code hereI have an ng-repeat in my ionic code. 
It gives me many duplicate values as the data is coming from CSV file. 
How can I stop this duplicate values from being shown ? 
Data shows XYZ values more than 5 times but I want it to be shown only once.

```
      <select ng-model="srcstn">
        <option   ng-repeat="x in from track by $index " >{{x.source}}</option>
      </select>
```

This is piece of code where m getting all duplicate values at {{x.source}}. and x.source has station names

Comment: Can't you just filter out the duplicates before displaying the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: @yadejo I would have done that but this is a client side data that m getting using API and I will not be able to change it because same is being used throughout the App for different features.

Comment: @Aniket can you please post your data and the criteria you want to filter on the basis of ?

Comment: @UsmanRana Sir, Data is in form of JSON string. Lets say I have 3 stations WFD,BLD,BNC. They will come in my select tag almost 5-6 times each. I just want them to come once. And I updated bit of a code there.

Comment: Ok. why don't you make a copy of this data and deal with it ? like `var copy = angular.copy($scope.from)`

Comment: I worked on it and its solved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'unique'(aliases: uniq) filter in angular.filter module

```
usage: colection | uniq: 'property'
```

you can also filter by nested properties:

```
 colection | uniq: 'property.nested_property'
```

try

```
<select ng-model="srcstn">
        <option   ng-repeat="x in from |uniq:'source'" >{{x.source}}</option>
      </select>
```