# cascading drop-down list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have created three dropdown buttons and want to populate them on the basis of selection from previous button.The data is in an object array as below:

```
[{"LINK":"B_LINK_01","NAME":"name-04","TYPE":"BB"},{"LINK":"A_LINK_01","NAME":"name-01","TYPE":"BB"},{"LINK":"C_LINK_01","NAME":"name-03","TYPE":"AA"},{"LINK":"C_LINK_05","NAME":"name-04","TYPE":"BB"}]
```

First drop-down should contain all unique TYPE values. When one of the TYPE is selected, the second drop-down should populate with all the unique NAME values corresponding to TYPE. When NAME is selected from second drop-down then the third drop-down should populate with all corresponding LINK values. For ex: The first dd should show BB, AA in the list. if I select BB then second drop-down should populate with name-04 and name-01. Next, if  I select name-04 then the third drop-down should populate with B_LINK_01 and C_LINK_05.

P.S. I have referred multiple tutorials and SO threads but did not find a solution relevant to the object array I have. Any help in Angular JS will be appreciated

Comment: No one is going to give you full code. You have to try this yourself. And if you stuck somewhere, then only post your question with relevant code on SO.

Comment: For the first one you need a [custom `unique` filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results), for the second a normal `filter` (to list objects with the same TYPE) along with a `unique` one (to remove duplicates), for the third I'm not sure, so figure that one out yourself

Comment: @Kenny : I have the code with me. Just wanted to know about the logic. I 'll update the question with my code

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: Thanks. I have used that filter in my code. I'll share the code