# At underscore js, Can I get multiple columns with pluck method after input where method as linq select projection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var people = [
    {firstName : "Thein", city : "ny", qty : 5},
    {firstName : "Michael", city : "ny", qty : 3},
    {firstName : "Bloom", city : "nj", qty : 10}
];

var results=_.pluck(_.where(people, {city : "ny"}), 'firstName');
```

For example : I need `firstName` and `qty`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To project to multiple properties, you need [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map), not pluck:

```
var results = _.map(
    _.where(people, {city : "ny"}), 
    function(person) {
        return { firstName: person.firstName, qty: person.qty };
    }
);
```

> [{"firstName":"Thein","qty":5},{"firstName":"Michael","qty":3}]

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm8YC/1/)

Note that, if you wanted to, you could create a helper method "pluckMany" that does the same thing as pluck with variable arguments:

```
// first argument is the source array, followed by one or more property names
var pluckMany = function() {
    // get the property names to pluck
    var source = arguments[0];
    var propertiesToPluck = _.rest(arguments, 1);
    return _.map(source, function(item) {
        var obj = {};
        _.each(propertiesToPluck, function(property) {
            obj[property] = item[property]; 
        });
        return obj;
    });
};
```

You can use the [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) function to add a "pluckMany" function to the `_` namespace.  Using this you can write simply:

```
var results = _.chain(people).where({city : "ny"}).pluckMany( "firstName", "qty").value();
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm8YC/16/)

Comment: Thanks McGarnagle; For passing parameter to pluckMany, is it good to pass array? I am a newbie and thinking about adopting underscore. I think mixin is equivalent to jquery plugin(fn).

Comment: @ttacompu The way I wrote it, you have to pass 1) array, and 2) multiple arguments.  You could modify it to accept either multiple arguments or an array as the second parameter ...

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR** Use :

```
var results = _.chain(people)
    .where({ city: "ny" })
    .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'firstName', 'qty'))
    .value();
```

But please read on for explanations as I feel the process of finding this solution is more interesting than the actual answer.

---

The general pattern would be (it works with [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) too) :

`_.map(array, function(obj) { return _.pick(obj, 'x', 'y', 'z'); });`

Given this general [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) function which transforms each element of a collection, there are multiple ways to adapt this to your particular situation (that vouch for the flexibility of `map`, which is a very basic building block of functional programs).

Let me present below several ways to implement our solution :

```
var _ = require('lodash'); // @lodash 2.4.1 at the time of writing
// use underscore if you want to, but please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore


/* la data */
var people = [{
    firstName: "Thein",
    city: "ny",
    qty: 5
}, {
    firstName: "Michael",
    city: "ny",
    qty: 3
}, {
    firstName: "Bloom",
    city: "nj",
    qty: 10
}];


/* OPTION1 : mixin' with _ */
_.mixin({
    pluckMany: function() {
        var array = arguments[0],
            propertiesToPluck = _.rest(arguments, 1);

        return _.map(array, function(item) {

            /* Alternative implementation 1.1
             * ------------------------------
             * Taken from @mMcGarnagle answer
             * _each is easy to understand here,
             * but has to modify the variable `obj` from a closure
             * I try to avoid that for trivial cases like this one.
             */
            var obj = {};
            _.each(propertiesToPluck, function(property) {
                obj[property] = item[property];
            });
            return obj;


            /* Alternative implementation 1.2
             * ------------------------------
             * Rewrite the previous code,
             * by passing the accumulator (previously`obj`, but really it is an object that accumulates the result being constructed) across function calls.
             * This construction is typical of the `reduce` function, closer to a functionnal programming style.
             */
            return _.reduce(propertiesToPluck, function(obj, property) {
                obj[property] = item[property];
                return obj;
            }, {});


            /* Alternative implementation 1.3
             * ------------------------------
             * If we are already using lodash/underscore,
             * then let's use the `pick` function ! I also included an example of `flatten` here
             */
            return _.pick(item, _.flatten(propertiesToPluck, true));


            /* Alternative implementation 1.4
             * ------------------------------
             * But really flatten is not needed.
             */
            return _.partial(_.pick, item).apply(null, propertiesToPluck);
        });
    }
});



/* Let's use our mixed function !
 * Since we call several _ functions on the same object
 * it is more readable to chain the calls.
 */
var results = _.chain(people)
    .where({
        city: "ny"
    })
    .pluckMany('firstName', 'qty')
    .value();



/* OPTION 2 : without mixing our code with lodash/underscore */
var results = _.chain(people)
    .where({
        city: "ny"
    })
    .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'firstName', 'qty'))
    .value();

console.log(results);
```

If you like this way of writing code with `underscore` or `lodash`, I highly suggest that you have a look at *functional programming*, as this style of writing as well as many functions (`map`, `reduce` amongst many others) come from there.

**Note :** This is apparently a common question in underscore :
https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1104

This is apparently no accident if these are left out of underscore/lodash : "composability is better than features". You could also say `do one thing and do it well`. This is also why `_.mixin` exists.

Comment: umm, so this should be the right answer :)

Also, pick can handle custom functions for whitelist / blacklisting props.

Comment: Re 'composability is better than features': the answer itself uses _.pick with multiple properties. With the above reasoning, there would be no feature for this, or _.pluck wouldn't even exist, as the solution above (map..pick) would work perfectly with one property too. So it feels uneven that pluck doesn't support multiple keys but pick does.

Comment: This is amazing - by far the most elegant way to do this proposed here to date. It also has the added advantage of unusually excellent composability - it's super-easy to add and remove steps from the process. Many kudos.

Comment: @AndrewFaulkner this is the beauty of using a functional style versus an imperative one. As a side node, I do not use underscore/lodash anymore, only http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/

Comment: Definitely! Using a more functional style is one of the guiding ideas I keep in mind in general when writing Javascript (and Ruby). I just find it leads to more maintainable and readable code when done correctly - especially when you pull in things like chaining. Your solution here fits that quite nicely IMHO. 
I'll have to check out ramdajs.

Comment: question references underscore.js but the TL-DR; of this answer references partialRight which is lodash-specific. Likewise the comment for OPTION 2, implies that the code will work in either.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, I wish `pluck` had an option of passing an array, but in the meantime, you could do:

```
const pluckFields = (arr, fields) => _.map(arr, item => _.pick(item, fields))
```

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is the author of the question wants to take an array of objects with many properties and strip each object down to a small list of properties.

There are myriad ways of doing so with _ , but I like this way best.  Pass in an empty result object which will be "this" inside the function.  Iterate with _each , and _pick the fields you want:

```
var myObjects = [
    { "first" : "eric",
      "last" : "gumbo",
      "code" : "x482"
    },
    { "first" : "john",
      "last" : "dinkman",
      "code" : "y9283"
    }
];

var result = [];
_.each( myObjects, function(itm) { this.push(_.pick(itm,"first","code")) }, result );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why use push to some unnecessary array inside the each instead of just using map?

Answer (score 1):

**YAAUu**-Yep Another Answer Using underscore...

```js
// use a proper browser to run this code snippet, a browser that is es6-compliant
let people = [{
    firstName: "Thein",
    city: "ny",
    qty: 5
  },
  {
    firstName: "Michael",
    city: "ny",
    qty: 3
  },
  {
    firstName: "Bloom",
    city: "nj",
    qty: 10
  }
];
// either you pick the properties you want 
let picking = _.iteratee((person) => _(person).pick("firstName", "city"));
// either you omit the properties you do not want
let omitting = _.iteratee((person) => _(person).omit("qty"));
// create the filter by city
let living = (people, city) => _(people).where({
  "city": city
});
// put the "filter by city" into a mixin (as I assume it would be used again & again)
_.mixin({
  living: living
});
// do the thing (twice), 
// these chaining methods could be done into a mixin as well
console.log("results by picking properties:", _(people).chain().living("ny").map(picking).value());
console.log("results by omitting properties:", _(people).chain().living("ny").map(omitting).value());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That one linear might save some lines:

```
var results=_.pick(_.where(people, {city : "ny"}), 'firstName', 'qty');
```

Answer (score -1):

We don't have to use pluck, omit do the trick as well.

```
var result = _.map(people, function(person) {
  return _.omit(person, 'city');
});
```