# AngularJS: How to load selected field by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

suppose there are so many fields in js object and i want to load only few not all. i was searching on this for getting answer. i got one but i am not sure this is right one.

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/js64b/14/

see this code `ng:repeat="(i,th) in head"` this is the way where we need to specify something in bracket. i have confusion here. so anyone can help me to understand how to load few selected data with `ng-repeat`. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not them all ? If your client side you have either already your whole objects or you have filtered bojects from server. Otherwise check the answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349881/at-underscore-js-can-i-get-multiple-columns-with-pluck-method-after-input-where. You could filtered all required fields in your controller into another list which you can bind to the scope so it won't be too heavy.

Comment: just tell me what kind of code it is `ng:repeat="(i,th) in head"` what the code is doing? what will be store in i & th ?

Comment: it seems that you luck basic knowledge of how ng-repeat works please have a look on the documentation and read on my answer, if further explanation is needed i would be happy to update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correct you want to know what the `(i,th)` values print:

First i suggest that you read on the `ng-repeat` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

`i` is the key of your object and `th` is the value:

```
scope.head = {
    a: "Name",
    b: "Surname",
    c: "City"
};
```

So for this object example that your provided `i` equals to a,b,c and `th` equals to "Name", "Surname","City"