# Are there any good underscore.js alternatives that extend the core js classes?

Tags: javascript, syntax, underscore.js

I find the `_.something(somevar, some_function_or_other_thing);` "syntax" quite ugly. What are some good alternatives that use ruby-like iterators and similar stuff:

```
10..times(function(i) {
   console.log(i);
});

uppercasefoobar = ["foo", "bar"].each(function(i) {
    return i.toUpperCase();
});
```

Also, I am using node.js, so it should focus more on the code than DOM stuff.

Comment: Probably nothing... There's a reason underscore does what it does. It's considered a very bad idea to pollute built-in types this way. You're essentially creating your own one-off version of the language that a) nobody understands and b) may break any given plugin/library.

Comment: Also, your version of `each` is actually a `map`. Also-also, `10.times` is never going to work in JavaScript, that's a syntax error an no library can alter the constraints of the language's syntax. If you want Ruby-isms in your JavaScript, consider CoffeeScript.

Comment: @meagar He's just providing an example

Comment: If you're looking for Ruby-ness, I recommend you try out CoffeeScript.

Comment: Also, if you really really like Ruby, you should check out CoffeeScript: http://coffeescript.org/

I'm not a huge fan of Ruby in general, but I would strongly suggest that you get a good grip on javascript (if you're new to it) before using coffeescript so you understand the nature of the language.

Comment: Ah damn. Apparently I should read comments. Just realized you're using CS. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one myself! http://sugarjs.com/

(and yes, I do realize extending native classes essentially forks the language... that is my motive...)

Answer (score 5):

Suprised no one mentioned [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com). Lo-Dash is a superset of Underscore, adding numerous methods. John-David Dalton (creator of Lo-Dash) explains the key differences between the two libraries in answering an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898916/1151943).

**edit:** found a detailed blog post ["Say hello to Lo-Dash"](http://kitcambridge.be/blog/say-hello-to-lo-dash/), detailing the background to the library and comparisons to other so called *'js utility belts'*.

Comment: Seconding this, nowadays Lo-Dash has superceded underscore and is superior in every way. It's a drop-in replacement too so you don't need to make any code changes, simply replace underscore with Lo-Dash and it works right out of the box!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're looking for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
uppercasefoobar = ["foo", "bar"].map(function(i) {
    return i.toUpperCase();
});
// uppercasefoobar == ["FOO", "BAR"]
```

With underscore.js you can also write:

```
_.range(10).forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

**Edit** You can also use:

```
_(3).times(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

Not a pretty as ruby syntax, but it gets the job done.

In general, underscore provides an object oriented version of most functions, where:

```
_.something(variable, params);
```

Is equivalent to

```
_(variable).something(params);
```

Comment: I was just providing an example of ruby-like syntax that could be implemented by said JS library (but I guess that one is already in ecmascript)

Comment: @phillips1012 underscore also provided an OOP wrapper for most functions, see my edited answer.