# Error: Failed to instantiate module restangular due to: '_' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, restangular

When first using Restangular on a working website I got the following JavaScript error:

> Failed to instantiate module restangular due to: '_' is undefined

What am I missing? What does it mean that '_' is undefined (in the Restangular module)?

Answer (score 34):

It's a simple oversight. The '_' (underscore) is a JavaScript utility library that Restangular uses and [depends](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#dependencies) on. Include [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) or [Undrescore](http://underscorejs.org/) library before the AngularJS library (in your HTML):

```html
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
```

PS: Double check the library script and path exist as referenced in your SCRIPT tag.

Additional readings:

- [Restangular Dependencies](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#dependencies)
- [Why Does Restangular Depend on lodash / underscore](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#why-does-this-depend-on-lodash--underscore)
- [Differences between lodash and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13789618/263901)

Comment: what if you're using browserify?