# Restangular - Not able to get started

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am learning Angularjs and Restangular. I am following this page http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/restangular.html

```
== app.js== 
angular.module('app', ['restangular']);

angular.module('app')
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','Restangular',
  function($scope,Restangular) {
    this.product="gem";
  }]);

== index.html ==
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/restangular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
        {{test.product}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i open index.html, it just opens {{test.product}}. But when i remove restangular references from app.js, it works fine. Paths to .js files are correct.

Please help me in getting this sorted.

Comment: Show the error message which is on your console. And you can use `console.log(angular.module('restangular'))` to check Restangular lib loaded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**==Solution==**

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr) told me that i should NOT be using minified version of angular.js as it doesn't show error in detail. I was getting this error:

> Error: Failed to instantiate module restangular due to: '_' is
>   undefined

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408290/error-failed-to-instantiate-module-restangular-due-to-is-undefined) i came to know that i was missing underscore/lodash which is a dependency of restangular. I included lodash in my html and everything worked fine then.

Comment: Good troubleshooting. You can mark your answer as THE answer. It might help somebody else :)