# How do you clone an array of objects using underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var _ = require('underscore');
var a = [{f: 1}, {f:5}, {f:10}];
var b = _.clone(a);
b[1].f = 55;
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

This results in:

```
[{"f":1},{"f":55},{"f":10}]
```

Clone does not appear to be working!
So I RTFM, and see this:

http://underscorejs.org/#clone

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

So `_.clone` is pretty useless.  Is there a way to actually copy the array of objects?

Comment: There was a pull request for deep copy that was denied: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/595 Lo-Dash has cloneDeep

Comment: lol I just realized the pun on underscore. Low dash.

Comment: underscore vs. lodash : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Well, there is a trick!  If clone does not "clone" nested objects, you can force it to by explicitly cloning each object inside a map call!  Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var _ = require('underscore');
var a = [{f: 1}, {f:5}, {f:10}];
var b = _.map(a, _.clone);       // <----
b[1].f = 55;
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Prints:

```
[{"f":1},{"f":5},{"f":10}]
```

Yay!  `a` is unchanged!  I can now edit `b` to my liking!

Comment: Be careful, though. This of course only works two levels deep. not for arrays or objects which are nested even more than this example.

Comment: By design, Underscore also won't clone RegExp or Date values properly

Comment: Anyone looking here should see my answer below.

Answer (score 69):

Another solution extracted [from the issue on Github](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/595#issuecomment-34858191) that works with any level of nested data, and does not require underscore:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: This works unless the object has a cycle, in which case `JSON.stringify` throws an error.  Which isn't the case in the original but is still an interesting state of affairs.  `a = {simple: 'thing'}; a.cycle = a ; JSON.stringify(a)`.

Comment: Also worth noting this solution only works for objects with simple types. For instance, if you're object has `Date` or `Regex` instances, they will be serialized to strings. Not the end of the world, but you need to handle it if you're using this and expect `Date` instances.

Comment: And if you think someone might try and feed `undefined` to this you'll want `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj) || null)` otherwise it'll throw an error.

Comment: Along with what @cayleyh mentioned, this will drop `function`s altogether.

Answer (score 14):

FWIW, lodash has a [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#cloneDeep) function:

> This method is like _.clone except that it recursively clones value.

Comment: It behaves differently with keys with undefined values though. So something to be aware of. Cloning `{a: 1, b: undefined}` with lodash will keep the undefined, but the parse/stringify version will remove them.

Answer (score 11):

[Underscore API reference](http://underscorejs.org/#toArray):

> `_.toArray(list)` Creates a real Array from the list (anything
>   that can be iterated over). Useful for transmuting the arguments
>   object.

...or in this case, *cloning* an array. Try this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var array1 =  [{a:{b:{c:1}}},{b:{c:{a:2}}},{c:{a:{b:3}}}];
var array2 = _.toArray(array1);
console.log(array1 === array2); --> false
console.log(array1[0] === array2[0]); --> true
```

---

The following is an addendum I created after Steve's comment below -thx

### A Vanilla JS (or using `_.clone` if wanted) [deep cloning recursive helper](https://gist.github.com/gdibble/e429544ab8fa931055b2f02a1ec5739d):

```
function clone(thing, opts) {
    var newObject = {};
    if (thing instanceof Array) {
        return thing.map(function (i) { return clone(i, opts); });
    } else if (thing instanceof Date) {
        return new Date(thing);
    } else if (thing instanceof RegExp) {
        return new RegExp(thing);
    } else if (thing instanceof Function) {
        return opts && opts.newFns ?
                   new Function('return ' + thing.toString())() :
                   thing;
    } else if (thing instanceof Object) {
        Object.keys(thing).forEach(function (key) {
            newObject[key] = clone(thing[key], opts);
        });
        return newObject;
    } else if ([ undefined, null ].indexOf(thing) > -1) {
        return thing;
    } else {
        if (thing.constructor.name === 'Symbol') {
            return Symbol(thing.toString()
                       .replace(/^Symbol\(/, '')
                       .slice(0, -1));
        }
        // return _.clone(thing);  // If you must use _ ;)
        return thing.__proto__.constructor(thing);
    }
}

var a = {
    a: undefined,
    b: null,
    c: 'a',
    d: 0,
    e: Symbol('a'),
    f: {},
    g: { a:1 },
    h: [],
    i: [ { a:2 }, { a:3 } ],
    j: [ 1, 2 ],
    k: function (a) { return a; },
    l: /[a-z]/g,
    z: [ {
        a: undefined,
        b: null,
        c: 'b',
        d: 1,
        e: Symbol(1),
        f: {},
        g: { b:2 },
        h: { c:{ c:3 } },
        i: { a:Symbol('b') },
        j: { a:undefined, b:null },
        k: [],
        l: [ 1, [ 1, 2 ], [ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ] ],
        m: function (a) { return !a; },
        n: { a:function (a) { return !!a; } },
        o: /(a|b)/i
       } ]
};
var b = clone(a);
var c = clone(a, { newFns:true });


/* Results - value beneath each for reference:

a.a === b.a --> true
undefined

a.b === b.b --> true
null

a.c === b.c --> true
'a'

a.d === b.d --> true
0

a.e === b.e --> false
Symbol(a)

a.f === b.f --> false
{}

a.g === b.g --> false
{ a:1 }

a.h === b.h --> false
[]

a.i === b.i --> false
[ { a:2 }, { a:3 } ]

a.i[0] === b.i[0] --> false
{ a:2 }

a.i[0].a === b.i[0].a --> true
2

a.j === b.j --> false
[ 1, 2 ]

a.k === b.k --> true
a.k === c.k --> false
function (a) { return a; }

a.l === b.l --> false
/[a-z]/g

a.z === b.z --> false
[Object]

a.z[0].a === b.z[0].a --> true
undefined

a.z[0].b === b.z[0].b --> true
null

a.z[0].c === b.z[0].c --> true
'b'

a.z[0].d === b.z[0].d --> true
1

a.z[0].e === b.z[0].e --> 
false
Symbol(1)

a.z[0].f === b.z[0].f --> false
{}

a.z[0].g === b.z[0].g -- > false
{ b:2 }

a.z[0].g.b === b.z[0].g.b --> true
2

a.z[0].h === b.z[0].h --> false
{ c:{ c:3 } }

a.z[0].h.c === b.z[0].h.c --> false
{ c:3 }

a.z[0].h.c.c === b.z[0].h.c.c --> true
3

a.z[0].i === b.z[0].i --> false
{ a:Symbol(b) }

a.z[0].i.a === b.z[0].i.a --> false
Symbol(b)

a.z[0].j === b.z[0].j --> false
{ a:undefined, b:null }

a.z[0].j.a === b.z[0].j.a --> true
undefined

a.z[0].k === b.z[0].k --> false
[]

a.z[0].l === b.z[0].l --> false
[ 1, [ 1, 2 ], [ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ] ]

a.z[0].l[1] === b.z[0].l[1] --> false
[ 1, 2 ]

a.z[0].l[1][1] === b.z[0].l[1][1] --> true
2

a.z[0].m === b.z[0].m --> true
a.z[0].m === c.z[0].m --> false
function (a) { return !a; }

a.z[0].n === b.z[0].n --> false
{ a:function (a) { return !!a; } }

a.z[0].n.a === b.z[0].n.a --> true
a.z[0].n.a === c.z[0].n.a --> false
function (a) { return !!a; }

a.z[0].o === b.z[0].o --> false
/(a|b)/i

*/
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: `_.toArray(list)` doesn't clone objects in an array.

`var array1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];`
`var array2 = _.toArray(array1);`
`array2[0].a = 999;`
`console.log(array1[0]); --> {a: 999}`

Comment: @SteveLang thanks for pointing that out.  Oops.
Therefore I took some time to make the vanilla JS fn above, which if the user really must can use the `_.clone` in the `else` condition ;)