# Vuex: getters not working after passing around state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am working on this `Vue` and `Vuex` website and I made an update but that broke the getters that depend on the "selected" state. I narrowed it down to the call of `SensorService.toggleSensor` but I don't know what the problem could be.

I have an action like so:

```
async toggleSensor({ state, commit }, sensor) {
    let selected = await SensorService.toggleSensor(state.selected, sensor);

    console.log(selected);

    await commit('updateSelected', selected);
},
```

and this is `SensorService.toggleSensor`:

```
async toggleSensor(selected, sensor) {
    let deviceId = await store.dispatch('chart/getDeviceIdBySensorId', sensor.id);

    let deviceAlreadySelected = false;
    let sensorAlreadySelected = false;

    for (let devId in selected) {
        if (devId === deviceId) {
            deviceAlreadySelected = true;

            for (let i = 0; i < selected[deviceId].length; i++) {
                if (selected[deviceId][i].id === sensor.id) {
                    sensorAlreadySelected;

                    // unselect sensor in case of it already being selected
                    Vue.delete(selected[deviceId], i); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (! deviceAlreadySelected) {
        selected[deviceId] = [sensor];
    }

    if (! sensorAlreadySelected && deviceAlreadySelected) {
        selected[deviceId].push(sensor);
    }

    return selected;
},
```

so when I replace `await commit('updateSelected', selected);` and hard code the data as in `await commit('updateSelected', {"deviceid": [{id: 1522, type: "temp"}]});` everything works so apparently the problem is with the call to `SensorService.toggleSensor` I just don't know what it could be? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by [simplified deep cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377904/1974790) `state.selected` before passing it to `SensorService`.

Though why this is necessary, I have no idea! Anyone?

Comment: It has buggy behavior in this version. If you want to delete something in the state you need to pass records to the state except deleted records. It seems mutable/immutable issue. @Peter Vasilev

Comment: @Batuhan is there some more info on this somewhere I am having further issues with this?

Comment: Now I can't delete sensors from `selected` inside the `SensorService` class for some reason. Bizarre.