# Underscore.js filter operation to create a list of object dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have done the following to loop through two List of objects in AngularJS and create a new List of object conditionally.

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.toUpdate = [];
for (var i = 0; i < changedItems.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < $scope.originalItems.length; j++) {
    if (changedItems[i].AttributeName == $scope.originalItems[j].AttributeName 
        && changedItems[i].Value != $scope.originalItems[j].Value) {
          $scope.toUpdate.push(changedItems[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am creating a list of object when the value is **changed** by the user (the `$scope.originalItems` has the original values).

I send it to the MVC controller to update the changes.

I am doing this because I don't need to update values those have not been changed.

This approach is making to many iterations.

**Requirement:**

I am sure that this can be **done** in a straight forward manner **using Underscore.js** but I am not able to do it.

Need help converting this logic into Underscore.

Comment: No underscore bashing here, and I'm not an expert, but you should check out 'lo-dash'. It was inspired by underscore, but should be more efficient and have more features. As seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore. I'm just commenting it here so you can check it out if your project is rather new and you can still easily replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be converted to Underscore like that:

```
_.each(item,function(i){
    _.each($scope.previous,function(p) {
         if (i.AttributeName == p.AttributeName && i.Value != p.Value) 
          $scope.toUpdate.push(i);
    });
});
```

But I think you want to avoid duplicating of items, then you can try this:

```
$scope.toUpdate = _.filter(item,function(i) {
    return _.any($scope.previous,function(p){
        return i.AttributeName == p.AttributeName && i.Value != p.Value;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz3v33hm/)

**Update**

Check following docs: [*.each*](http://lodash.com/docs#each) [.filter](http://lodash.com/docs#filter) [_.any](http://lodash.com/docs#any)

Comment: your solution works but may I know the way your solutions work?

Comment: Check Lodash's docs (Absolutely agree with Tsasken, it's way too improved than Underscore)

Comment: And btw: could you rephrase your question on "how solution work" :)