# Check existence of an element in a nested javascript object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a Javascript object in the following format

```
{
"Alerts": [{
        "Name": "...",
        "Type": "Warning",
        "Message": "...",
        "Time": "..."
    },
    {
        "Name": "...",
        "Type": "Critical",
        "Message": "...",
        "Time": "..."
    },
    {
        "Name": "...",
        "Type": "Info",
        "Message": "...",
        "Time": "..."
    }]
}
```

How do I check if an alert of the type **Critical** exists anywhere in this array object I receive.

I am using angularjs.

Comment: use underscore.js. you can use find method.

Comment: Or lodash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore

Comment: if(data.Alerts.filter(function pluck(a){return a[this]}, "Message").indexOf("Critical")!==-1){ alert("oh noes!");}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching angular kind of thing,
Create a filter,

```
app.filter('checkCritical', function() {
    return function(input) {
         angular.forEach(input, function(obj) {
             if((obj.Type).toLowerCase() == 'critical') {
                return true;
             }
         });
         return false;
    };

})
```

use this filter inside the controller

in controller,

```
var exists = $filter("checkCritical").(Alerts);
```

dont forget to inject the `$filter` in to the controller

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
function find(arr, key, text){
    for(var i = arr.length; i--;){
        if(arr[i][key] === text) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage

```
var index = find(jsonObject.Alerts, "Type", "Critical")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery on the page.

```
var exists = $.grep(alerts, function (e) { return e.Type == 'Critical'; }).length > 0;
```

Note: `alerts` (as above) will be the array of alerts you have in your object there.

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to loop through each element of the array and check to see if any objects have 'Critical' as the Type property value.