# Using lodash instead of underscore in Backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

I'm writing a Backbone application and as I'm reading the documentation online, what I understand is that Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore. However, I'd like to use Lodash instead of Underscore. Can someone provide steps as to how I can do this?

Comment: backbone depends a lot on underscore to get it job done. you might need to write complete library again in case you dont want to use underscore

Comment: 1. Include lodash.js instead of underscore.js, 2. Done

Comment: replace underscore with lodash and fix possible errors) just wondering what are you going to reach by this replace?

Comment: @Evgeniy lodash has some features that underscore lack, if OP wants to use those features it makes more sense to replace underscore than to add both.

Comment: As I remember, in our project we've just replaced an import of underscore with lodash and that's all. @Evgeniy, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13898916/1203773

Comment: @EugeneNaydenov thanks for the SO link you provided! super helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Browserify, check out [Browserify Swap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-swap) or [Aliasify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aliasify)

Personally I use Browserify Swap. Example package.json usage:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-swap"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-swap": {
    "@packages": [
      "underscore"
    ],
    "all": {
      "underscore.js$": "lodash"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - will definitely try this!

Answer (score 3):

Up to version 2.4.1, lodash published a "Underscore compatible" version.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js

You can use that as a drop-in replacement.

As of 3.0, they removed this build.

> Removed the underscore build

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog

Comment: There is documentation on doing a custom build and setting the moduleId to underscore https://lodash.com/custom-builds

Answer (score 2):

You could also check out [Exoskeleton](http://paulmillr.com/exoskeleton/) - it's a drop-in replacement for Backbone that doesn't have Underscore as a requirement so you can simply remove it (and use lodash instead of it).