# Use underscore and lodash in same project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

In my project one module has implemented using underscore library. Now for going forward we need to use lodash.For injecting lo-dash in project
 `angular.module('myModule').constant('_', window._);` we have to depend on window.
As we are using underscore library in same project it is also accessible by “`window._`”. As both of them uses “window._” there will be ambiguity of one over another. What is the solution for this? am using this in angular JS Project.

Comment: Perhaps you could bin underscore and just use lodash from now on?  [lodash is just a superset of underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13898916/1136527), so I doubt you'll run into any problems

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict and https://lodash.com/docs#noConflict

Comment: https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash using this will be good idea??

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Do i need to make any changes in code where underscore is already used. or lodash is compatible with underscore functionality. As one complete module uses underscore functionality.