# Javascript (jquery) functionality similar to linq's Where()

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq

Is it possible to do in jquery something similar to this C# example:

```
LoopModel = Model.Fields
                    .Where(p => p.Key < 1000 && !Model.FieldHandled.ContainsKey(p.Key) && !FieldsValid.ContainsKey(p.Key))
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Value.SortOrder).ThenBy(p => p.Value.FieldTypeID).ThenBy(p => p.Value.FieldLabel);
```

I can do

```
var fields = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Fields));
```

So I want to be able to select certain fields from "fields".

Thanks

Comment: Use `JLinq.js` library. It provides same `linq` functions as `C#`

Comment: @Akshay Thanks, would you like to make it an answer, so that I could mark it?

Comment: what is  `FieldsValid` what is `FieldHandled`? instead `where` in c# you can use `filter` in js, instead `orderBy` - `sort`

Answer (score 2):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).  No libraries required.

Here is an example from the link:

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Comment: only for new browsers :-)

Comment: IE 9 is a new browser?  I guess this isn't appropriate if you need to support IE 8, but I wouldn't think that would be worth it unless you're specifically targeting a userbase more likely to still be using it.

Comment: some mobile browsers also not available this :-)

Comment: It shows compatibility at the bottom of that link, and there's a tab for mobile.  Apparently, it's supported for all of them but I can't verify that.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Lodash or Underscore. They are widely used in various JS libs and right now I think they are the most JavaScript-ish solution. They also guarantee support for legacy browsers, having lots of performance enhancements. I think it's worth to learn them.

https://lodash.com/ http://underscorejs.org/

See the comparison here: [Differences between lodash and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JLinq.js` library. It provides same functions as `C#`