# Javascript Make object with variable path

Tags: javascript

I have object

```
var o = {
   first{
      aa: 1,
      bb: 2,
      cc: 3
   },
   second: {
      aa: 2,
      dd: 1,
      ee: 10
   }
}
```

I need to return new object with same structure but only one property.

```
getProperty('second.aa');

getProperty = function(path){
   _.each(path.split('.'), function(){
      //....
   });
   // need return {second: {aa: 2}}
}
```

Maybe there are good solutions with underscore or angularjs?
Thanx!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference) is a good solution

Comment: With [lodash](https://lodash.com/): http://jsfiddle.net/o8s3osbx/

Comment: Very nice, thanx! But I'm looking for the same solution with underscore

Comment: And why not lodash? lodash is a superset of underscore and they are planning to merge them into one library. [Differences between lodash and underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore), [The Big Kahuna: Underscore + Lodash Merge Thread](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2182)

Comment: Coz I already use underscore in my project. So I don't want to use both libs.. When they will merge - it will be awesome