# How can I merge javascript two objects but only update properties that change

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to write a function that will let me update my `kitchen` in this example below. Using something like underscore's `extend`, however, blows away the beer in my fridge as it's updating the entire `fridge` object.

Is there a simple method I can use so that I only make updates with the properties that change in my `changeKitchen` object and not update the entire `fridge` object?

```
// My original kitchen
var kitchen = {
  fridge: {
    beer: true,
    celery: false
  },
  cabinets: {
    candy: true
  }
};


// updates I would like to make to my kitchen
var changeKitchen = {
  fridge: {
    celery: true
  }
};


var updatedKitchen = _.extend(kitchen, changeKitchen);

console.log(updatedKitchen);
```

Returns

```
var kitchen = {
  fridge: {
    celery: false // beer is gone
  },
  cabinets: {
    candy: true
  }
};
```

However I would like to have:

```
var kitchen = {
  fridge: {
    beer: true,
    celery: true // changed
  },
  cabinets: {
    candy: true
  }
};
```

Comment: have you try `extend` from jQuery with `deep` option ;) https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: You can also do this in lodash using merge.

Comment: I did not, thanks @LongNguyen. Would be nice if underscore had this option :/  https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/162. Though it looks like lodash `_.merge` might be simillar

Comment: ah, just beat me. thanks @AtheistP3ace

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already using Underscore, you could use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) instead, which is a superset of Underscore, and use its [`#merge`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) function.

See this question about [Differences between Lodash and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore)

```js
// My original kitchen
var kitchen = {
  fridge: {
    beer: true,
    celery: false
  },
  cabinets: {
    candy: true
  }
};


// updates I would like to make to my kitchen
var changeKitchen = {
  fridge: {
    celery: true
  }
};


var updatedKitchen = _.merge(kitchen, changeKitchen);

document.write(JSON.stringify(updatedKitchen));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.extend` on the nested objects instead:

```
function update(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var p in obj2) {
    if (obj1[p]) {
        _.extend(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
    } else {
      obj1[p] = obj2[p];
    }
  }
}

update(kitchen, changeKitchen);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ny27ww3/1/)

Comment: This won't work if `obj1` doesn't have the corresponding property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in plain Javascript:

```js
var kitchen = { fridge: { beer: true, celery: false }, cabinets: { candy: true } },
    changeKitchen = { fridge: { celery: true } };

function update(source, target) {
    Object.keys(target).forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof target[k] === 'object') {
            source[k] = source[k] || {};
            update(source[k], target[k]);
        } else {
            source[k] = target[k];
        }
    });
}

update(kitchen, changeKitchen);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(kitchen, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for..in` loop , `Object.keys()`

```js
// My original kitchen
var kitchen = {
  fridge: {
    beer: true,
    celery: false
  },
  cabinets: {
    candy: true
  }
};

var changeKitchen = {
  fridge: {
    celery: true
  }
};

for (var prop in changeKitchen) {
  if (kitchen[prop]) {
    kitchen[prop]
      [Object.keys(changeKitchen[prop])] = changeKitchen[prop]
         [Object.keys(changeKitchen[prop])]
  }
}

console.log(kitchen)
```