# get total count of all types and group(type) based count using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to get total count of all types and group based count of below json array.

```
   var json = {"items":[                            
                  {"type":1,"count":10},
                  {"type":1,"count":10},
                  {"type":2,"count":20},
                  {"type":1,"count":30},
                  {"type":1,"count":40},
                  {"type":2,"count":100}                            
          ]
        }
```

I want to get total count of all types (AllTypeTotal:210) and seperate count of type1(TypeOneTotal:90) and type2(TypeTwoTotal:120).

So I am expecting following array:

```
    var json = { 
                "AllTypeTotal":210, 
                "TypeOneTotal":90,
                "TypeTwoTotal":120
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using Underscore's [**reduce**](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) or the native [**array.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Here's an underscore solution:

```
var result = _.reduce(json.items, function(memo, item){

    // build the correct key
    var key = 'Type' + item.type + 'Total';

    // update the total
    memo.AllTypeTotal += item.count;

    // update the type total
    memo[key] = (memo[key] | 0) + item.count;

    return memo;
}, { AllTypeTotal: 0 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with [lodash](https://lodash.com/) which is a superset of underscore and much better than underscore when it comes to performance and consistency (see [lodash vs underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore)).

```
var uniqTypes = _.pluck(_.uniq(json.items, "type"), "type");
var result = {};
uniqTypes.forEach(function(typeName){
    result["type"+typeName+"total"] = 0;
    _.map(data.items, function(item){
         if(item.type === typeName) 
             result["type"+typeName+"total"] += item.count;
    });
});
```