# Merge two json objects on the server side

Tags: javascript, json

I have inherited an express application. In the application we pass to [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) a massive list of local variables. For every page we pass about 30 variables that do not change. If one does change it needs to be changed in a dozen places. This is obviously bad.

So what I want to do store the values locals that do not change separate from the truly local. So I placed these non-changing values in their own file and load the file at the start of each route, like so:

```
'use strict';
var locals = 
{
    indexName: 'Home',
    ...lots more of these...
};
module.exports = { locals : locals };


// in each route files
var local = require('../locals.js');
```

And I can use it via `res.render('sensor', local.locals);`

However I also need to add page specific values. So I tried `local.locals + { ... };` which doesn't while it doesn't give an error doesn't even show the original values.

I then tried `local.locals.concat({...})` but that does give an error (`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'concat'`), likewise for `extend` and `push`.

Is there no methods to extend or merge two objects? Do I need to roll my own?

Also, is this the best way of making the an array global? I would prefer just to call it `locals`, and not `local.locals` as that is just cumbersome.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'assign'` for that too.

Comment: After looking at the `Object.assign` documentation I changed the parameters and now I get `TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'`. I will look at lodash.

Comment: `Object.assign` is a static member function but you are trying to use it as instance member function. I don't get why you don't google it properly. This is not rocket science if you have a C++ background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) from @mostruash, there are two JS libraries that are very similar, which both provide an object merge function (along with a lot of nice helper utilities). Pick one:

- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)
- [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)

Edit: and as to your second question about `local.locals`...of course, just export the object itself, rather than an object that wraps it:

```
module.exports = locals;
```

...and in your routes:

```
var locals = require('../locals');
console.log(locals.indexName);
```

Comment: Note that it may be a better idea to use lodash. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore

Comment: Finally used lodash `assign`.