# _.uniq and _.groupBy function underscore library

Tags: underscore.js

I came across underscore library during my work. I want to use `_.uniq` and `_.groupBy` function. Can someone explain how these work?

I tried to remove duplicate from array of object based on 1 property, but it did not work.

For example:

```
array = [{'name': 'a', 'age': 18}, '{'name': 'a', 'age': 18}']
```

I used like:

```
uniq_arr =_.uniq(array, 'age')
```

--> wanted to take unique object based on "age". 
---> **Did Not Work**

Then wanted to group them based on "name". 
    group_arr = _.groupBy(uniq_arr, 'name').
---> **"Worked"**

My questions/doubts are:

1. `groupby` worked fine for me but `uniq` did not work. So anyone can explain how to get my expected result using `uniq`?
2. If I want to use nested `groupBy`, how should I write that? I mean the syntax.

Also, It will be a great help, If someone can guide me the proper resource from where I can understand these functions in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really about angularjs at all, it is entirely about the underscore-library.

Personally, I believe the documentation of [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) explain the functionality pretty well.

> **groupBy** _.groupBy(list, iteratee, [context])
>
> Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each value through iteratee. If iteratee is a string instead of a function, groups by the property named by iteratee on each of the values.
>
> ```
> _.groupBy([1.3, 2.1, 2.4], function(num){ return Math.floor(num); });
> => {1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4]}
> ```
>
> **uniq** _.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee]) Alias: unique
>
> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. In particular only the first occurence of each value is kept. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.
>
> ```
> _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3]);
> => [1, 2, 4, 3]
> ```

The following snippet explains the result of your examples:

```js
console.log("Test data:");
var array = [
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 18},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 18},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 19},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 20},
  {'name': 'c', 'age': 19},
];
console.log(array);

console.log("_.uniq(array, 'age') -> Removes elements to only hold one of each age (names will be ignored entirely):");
var uniq_arr =_.uniq(array, 'age');
console.log(uniq_arr);

console.log("_.groupBy(array, 'name') -> Creates a dictionary where each name holds an array of all elements that match that name:");
var group_arr = _.groupBy(array, 'name');
console.log(group_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

As for your question about "nested groupBy", if you simply want to group twice in a row, then you could do something like this:

```js
var array = [
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 18},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 18},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 19},
  {'name': 'a', 'age': 20},
  {'name': 'c', 'age': 19},
];

var group_arr = _.groupBy(array, 'name');
for (var key in group_arr) {
  group_arr[key] = _.groupBy(group_arr[key], 'age');
}
console.log(group_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

*Side note: I would suggest switching from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to [lodash](https://lodash.com/).
See [differences-between-lodash-and-underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore).*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your example worked perfectly fine . I don't know why unique logic did not work when I used.
For nested group ->  first group by name , and then on that group again group on age. Sorry, I am not able to give you expected output , as I am not able to visualize the output format.

And , thanks for pointing out to use 'lodash' library . I will surely look into that.

Comment: @shubham I've added the "nested group" to my answer, assuming that you wanted to group the outer collections by `name` and the inner by `age`. Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your question?

Comment: this is absolutely correct. I was looking for the same. Thanks a lot.